# Is this question a good fit for Stack Overflow, after typo corrected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

EDIT: my question has now been put on hold as "off topic for having a simple typographic error", despite the fact that the typo was in my logs and not in the code and did not affect the problem!!!

I made a typo in the following question:

[Cannot compile any C++ programs; error: unknown type name 'uint8_t'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029309/cannot-compile-any-c-programs-error-unknown-type-name-uint8-t)

The typo made it look like I compiled some C++ code with a gcc instead of g++. A user kindly alerted me to the issue and I updated the question accordingly. However, I got a lot of downvotes, seemingly because of the typo, and a few users even accused me of faking the logs to make it seem like I had not made a mistake.

This is behavior I would expect on Reddit, not Stack Overflow. I made a mistake, and I updated it. If the question I asked was bad for the community I would like to know so that I may write better ones in the future. However, outside of the typo, my question included a MVCE, links to other things I have tried, and the error message.

What did I do to inspire the community's rage in this case and how can I improve?

Comment: +2/-5 is not bad for a train wreck in the C/C++ tag....

Comment: @rene what train wreck? My problem exists in both C and C++.

Comment: I'm not yet so intoxicated that I don't understand what your question is about. My humor might suck but that is about it.

Comment: @JosephFarah rene only made a joke, good luck with your question, it is actually very good for someone trying to get the [Waffles hat](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/waffles)

Comment: @rene sorry if i am a little frustrated right now. this problem has been bogging me for weeks, and to be accused of faking logs for no clear purpose is quite demoralizing.

Comment: @eLRuLL thanks for the clarification :) although I am the question asker haha

Comment: I don't have a Mac so I can't try myself, but so far it looks like nobody can reproduce your issue. While that's not your fault, it would indeed make the question a poor fit for this site because the only answer that can come from this would be "Something's wrong with your system.". And that is hardly useful for anyone.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I had a feeling that would be the problem, but I wasn't sure, and I also tried to include SO links from other people that had the same issue. You're totally correct, after the fact it is clear it was an incredibly system specific issue, but I am grateful for the help I got from the site :)

Comment: @rene  You clearly haven't seen the *real* train wreck tho... :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your question got a lot of downvotes because you tagged C and C++ for no reason.

> [Kev](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev)'s Note - being down voted for mistagging a question is
>   moronic and unnecessarily hostile. I truly despair sometimes when this
>   kinda thing happens. The correct behaviour would have been to edit the
>   tags and leave an explanation.

There are a lot of problems about tagging question with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), and a lot of questions already exist because if these problems:

- *[How can we stop SO suggesting both C and C++ tags on questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions)*
- *[Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags/252433#252433)*
- *[User goes into edit war for C tag removal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350785/user-goes-into-edit-war-for-c-tag-removal/350801#350801)*
- *[Question is tagged both [c] and [c++], but has no reason to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358560/question-is-tagged-both-c-and-c-but-has-no-reason-to-be)*

Your question had nothing to do with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). In fact, your question may not need [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) because your code is perfectly valid (but as OP you can't know this so put [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag is good as well as your MCVE). Tag [g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) would be logical because your question seems to be about a compilation problem with `g++`. Recently, Lundin has created a very nice [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360824/7076153) about how/when tag both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tags.

Comment: Note: I remove the C tag from your question and upvote it just after, like you saw a lot of user reverse your score at 0 ;). Like @rene said, it's not a bad score when you know you start the question with both C and C++ tags for no reason ;)

Comment: Ohhhhhh it was the tagggggggggg. Thanks Star. I'm not gonna lie, I have been super confused for like the past few hours. I thought it was because of the typo (because a few other users accused me of lying about the logs I was putting up) so I assumed thats what the downvotes were about. But it was the tag. Thanks for clearing that up! And thanks for the resources about The Tag Wars: Attack of the C++lones. I'm glad there's a clear and easy way I can improve my questions :)

Comment: The problem with having only [tag:g++] would be that most of the C++ programmers on Mac who would have knowledge about this, wouldn't necessarily be following it...

Comment: *"Your question got a lot of downvotes because you tagged C and C++ for no reason."* - being down voted for mistagging a question is moronic and unnecessarily hostile. I truly despair sometimes when this kinda thing happens. The correct behaviour would have been to edit the tags and leave an explanation.

Comment: @Kev True, this is what I did in fact ;), but if I can't find the language that the OP truly use, I generally close it as unclear or too broad.

Comment: @Stargateur - apologies, I wasn't accusing you of down voting. Ultimately, in Joseph's defence, he asked the question in good faith. Not everyone knows the almost 10 year long minutiae of meta discussions over correct tagging, and like many devs may not have the time to explore our meta history. I'm surprised he hasn't walked away from the site seeing how his question was handled by the community.There are far worse crimes happening on SO compared to this genuine ask for help. Anyway, Happy New Year etc :)