# Why is this comment not considered rude?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rude-or-abusive

On another meta discussion, I came across this [highly upvoted comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350785/users-go-into-edit-war-about-c-tag?noredirect=1#comment482298_350785):

> Spending your free time in the [c] and [c++] tag is like taking
>   vacation in Syria. You have to participate in the jihad and shall pick
>   a side. Taking a break on the breezy [c#] coast is not a bad idea, it
>   has a lot less religion.

Now, I get it. This is tongue-in-cheek, metaphorical, humorous, not-taking-life-so-seriously, etc, etc.  I did not find it offensive personally, but I can absolutely see that it *can* be offensive to a wide range of people. In fact, I *know* people who would find it offensive, for their own reasons.

There are plenty of ways to be humorous without having to reference sensitive issues such as politics, war, religion, gender. Burnination request titles are good examples of humor that avoids these topics.

I flagged this comment as Rude / Abusive. My flag was declined.  **Does this comment have a place on (meta) SO?**

**Update / Context**:

I skimmed around 20 pages of comments each for 4 users who are active contributors to Meta. It took a couple of hours. I did this because I wanted to see whether offensive comments *really are upvoted* by the community: is the problem systemic or isolated? I chose users who are active contributors to Meta. Three had nothing offensive. The remaining one had an unenviable number of infractions, *many very highly upvoted*. Frankly, I was shocked the vituperative stream I found was held in such high esteem. Trust me, it wasn't *all* humour. **The fact that moderators largely agreed with me only suggests I was right to flag.**

I selected the comment in this question because I know people who find it offensive *and* it was declined *and* it has a huge upvote count.

Comment: meh. I don't agree with flagging things because it may be offensive to someone else... that someone else should flag it. That's not a rabbit hole i want to go down.

Comment: @KevinB, Great point. Except it doesn't affect moderation. Should a moderator consider *who* is flagging and *their* intention? That opens up a whole new dimension to moderation criteria..

Comment: Why get offended over something that wasn't intended to be offensive? This comment isn't meant to be rude or offensive. There are FAR worse cases out there.

Comment: The "bring your sense of humor" from the "be nice" page really, really applies. We all need to chill out a bit. IMO, the flag was correctly declined.

Comment: I really dislike seeing these aggressively cynical comments on so many meta posts. Yeah, we can tell it's not meant to be offensive, and we know it's because users are tired of dealing with the issues they're talking about. But I don't think it's unreasonable to want to have a conversation without that style of comment.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?  It appears that this meta question is genuinely interested in discussion and it has a directly answerable question.  If you disagree, why not write an answer?

Comment: @davidism I do think it is unreasonable to expect that the conversation absolutely agreeable in tone to everyone in a public site on the Web. We do target rude comments, but there has to be leeway and space for some spectrum in what we consider rude or not.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I think you must know than in meta votes many times are used to express disagreement. It's also a valid form of expression.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't think I've ever seen a meta post asking if a comment or post should be considered rude that *didn't* get a ton of down votes and that's including a meta question where a woman reported being called a whore (and no, the word 'rep' didn't occur in front of that).

Comment: @yivi https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350785/users-go-into-edit-war-about-c-tag?noredirect=1#comment482298_350785

Comment: @yivi OP felt bullied by this comments author, so now he is looking for a way to revenge.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB. Wasn't really looking for the specific comment, but I have to say I find it interesting that it is another jpp/Hans interaction. I guess that this is what BrackNicku meant, it completely flew over my head.

Comment: To give more context to my question, for many users English is a 2nd (or 3rd, or 4th) language. Equally, Western standards of humour are not adopted worldwide. An easy way out is avoid stuff like religion, gender, politics. You can still be funny without these, many people manage it here and elsewhere.

Comment: mentioning religion/politics though doesn't inherently make something rude or offensive.

Comment: @yivi I think the whole downvotes as disagreement is way over-emphasized.  That was originally intended for feature requests, which this question is not.  This appears to be asking a genuine question about where SO draws the line on rude/abusive comments and flagging such comments.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Whatever you and I feel about it, it's the way votes are generally used in meta. So it seems disingenuous to imply otherwise here, IMO.

Comment: @jpp please add the context for this comment.  Is this from meta?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Given the context of the last question the OP posted, plus the context Kevin B linked, I certainly understand why this is getting downvoted. (The context from Kevin also made me retract my previous comment.)

Comment: @KevinB: "*Why get offended over something that wasn't intended to be offensive? This comment isn't meant to be rude or offensive.*" That simply means it was made thoughtlessly. Does mindlessness insulate someone from being rude or offensive? I don't see why it should. You *ought* to be expected to put some thought into the things you say. And if you can't be bothered, then you should expect to be occasionally slapped down for stepping over lines you aren't paying attention to.

Comment: Beyond this specific comment, your targeting of this user's comments by going through their history and flagging them *en masse* leaves a bad taste in my mouth. This is starting to look like a vendetta against someone.

Comment: @PeterHaddad, Many users come to Meta for advice. Surely it should be *more* friendly?

Comment: User targetting and stalking in this manner is a big no-no. Especially trying to manipulate meta into being a tool to win battles in your personal vendettas. Not to mention that it feels like you must think we're  incredibly stupid if you thought we weren't going to put the pieces together. I'm sure this is all culminating into something, I just hope it isn't too disruptive.

Comment: Then there's the fact that you posted a meta question to say, "I don't think this comment is actually offensive, but I flagged it as offensive anyway, and the flag was declined, why was the flag declined?"  Given that even the flagger didn't think the comment was offensive, the answer seems rather self-evident, and discussing it unnecessary.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and me!  Hey, if we are all offended by everything, maybe we can all agree to not bother flagging everyday stuff as rude/offensive and use the flag for what it is actually meant for instead of some sword for stabbing people we don't like.  The 'Be nice' policy, as currently implemented,  is rapidly becoming even more of a joke than it already was:(

Comment: `"I skimmed around 20 pages of comments each for 4 users who are active contributors to Meta. It took a couple of hours"` -- If this is what you did, and the flag above is one of the worst you could come up with, then you were truly wasting your own time

Comment: `"The fact that moderators largely agreed with me only suggests I was right to flag."` -- Sure the comment that you flagged was not the best, but there is so much content that is far worse than the comment above, that truly needs to be gotten rid of and that the moderators *should* be focusing on, that this diversion or personal vendetta of yours also wasted the moderator's time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Sorry, the *personal vendetta* issue is something that has been attributed to me. Well, what can I do about this? Precisely nothing but carry on. Correctly flag rude/abusive material. Make SO a better place. That is reward enough. I won't question a specific decision again because I know how it will end. (This is exactly what I recently suggested [elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365911/rude-flag-was-dismissed?noredirect=1#comment574166_365911).)

Answer (score 29):

I agree that the comment you flagged was in poor taste.  It certainly could have been deleted in my opinion.  But that's not the whole story for why this specific flag on this comment was declined.

We'd have to get the moderator who declined it specifically to explain definitively, but I think your flag had the appearance of being raised **not in good faith**.  It was a flag raised on a old comment on an old post that was last 3 active months ago.  And it was raised against a user that you've had some confrontations with already on meta, and [you might have been targeting this user with you flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365937/why-is-this-comment-not-considered-rude?noredirect=1#comment573736_365937).

Besides all that, highly upvoted comments often get preferential treatment, and moderators are usually more hesitant to delete them.  Additionally, meta's standards are laxer than the main site, and maybe that also played a role in the declined flag.

Comment: I think you summed up all that there is to be said tbh. Bonus points for being someone with a disinterested view of the situation.

Comment: I think flaggers are not shown to the mods?

Comment: @user202729: they are, but we have to follow through several clicks to find that info.

Comment: the fact that the comment  was highly upvoted can be even more rude to ones who'd get offended by it, so if by "preferential treatment" you mean taken even more seriously, than that's a good thing indeed.

Answer (score 13):

I deleted the comment.

While I don't think the author's intent was to offend anyone, the analogy was in really poor taste. I found it to be in poor taste, as did others that wrote to us, and ***I'm not going to waste anyone else's time on a stinky comment*** than has already gone into this.

When you build an analogy on humans hurting each other, it, well, reminds folks of humans hurting each other. Meta is strange enough without us enshrining stuff like that.

#### Nobody here acted in bad faith or did anything wrong.

The mistake was spending any more time on it than was needed to go through the following flow chart:

- Does it require extended discussion to defend?

  - (yes) Is it a comment?

    - (yes) Just delete it and move on. ***Comments are ephemeral, always have been, always will be.*** We're a bit more lenient here on meta, but if we have to sit down and have a whole discussion about *is this bad? smells like it could be ...* ***then just throw it out.***

There's more to this than just decisions made, what looks like a 'grudge' can introduce some bias. That's .. a fundamental flaw of the flagging system especially when it pertains to comments that I think we're going to need to have a look at.

Let's not waste any more time on it beyond figuring out what we can learn to (1) make sure people feel like we're a good place to spend time and (2) not get sucked into rule-lawyering when there's bigger things to think about.