# Policing in the aftermath of The Blog Post of Welcomingness

Tags: discussion, etiquette, welcoming

I want to talk about taking action in our trying time of [The Blog Post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). Consider it a plea for sanity.

[image: how about no]

#### Background

I know the problems concerning minority groups are very real even on Stack Overflow. As privileged as I can be I don't feel these on my own skin, so examples [have to be](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309908/diminishing-numbers-of-women-in-programming-and-the-so-experience) explicitly [pointed out to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364891/reasonable-suggested-edit-but-inappropriate-edit-summary). I'd love to have a Stack Overflow where nobody cares about who or what the other users are.

Now, I think the blog post is the worst thing that could happen in this matter, for the reasons explained in the many meta posts spawned since, such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366757/on-the-false-dichotomy-between-quality-and-kindness) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/when-is-stack-overflow-going-to-stop-demonising-the-quality-concerned-users-who). At first I was glad to see that Stack Overflow is stepping up to Do Something. Then I read the blog post and I got an uneasy feeling. Then eventually I realized that the uneasy feeling is mere cognitive dissonance: I very much agree with making SO better, but mixing *post quality* into the picture was really out of place. My confusion turned to anger; now I'm just frustrated.

I'm sure I'm not alone with these concerns. There are a *lot* of kinds of people here, and most of them are probably stirred now, and not for the better.

1. People such as myself are angry and frustrated because, while we agree with the point on inclusiveness, the possible quality-control implications just make no sense.
2. A huge chunk of our users are not even aware that the underlying problem is real. And when they see that blog post, many of them will just tick a mental box that someone's being socially oversensitive again, which in the (not-so-)long run will only make the real problem that much worse (see crying wolf and whatnot). This also goes back to point 1.
3. I suspect the actual population the blog post is trying to help will be much worse off right now. This is a very emotional time for the site (considering the usual professional atmosphere), and I fear every bias will be amplified. I've seen a lot of comments on main arguing about welcomingness. Additional arguing and hate will never solve the problem of welcomingness.

#### What to do

I hope the aim of the blog post was just to spark discussion (meta-phor remark: sparks are great unless the place and context is bad, such as when there are open gasoline barrels around). So let's do that: talk about the problems. Talk about what problems there are, talk about what problems there aren't, and try to be open to people who occupy a different stance from your own. Let's figure out what the community thinks, and get rid of all the accidental baggage piled up on the problem by the blog post. If we can start talking about the real problem with no distractions (such as the problem of quality control) we may be able to effect change.

#### What not to do

Please, try not to *take action* along the lines of the real or perceived message of the blog post. So many people have conflicting interpretations; there's no way you can get it right if you try to follow the perceived guidance.

Only two days after the blog post I saw a bunch of flags in chat that ended up in some Twitter shaming and a meta post. There was a questionably appropriate but completely civil and non-offensive discussion hours before the flagging. The first suggestion in the corresponding meta post was

> There is a solution. Let's all flag as spam/offensive. These messages should be removed from the chat forthwith. I'm not judge & jury, but in my opinion, these users should be banned for a week. They have rep to protect, so it matters. It may not be targeted abuse, but trivialising prostitution definitely doesn't fit under "Be Nice".

Uuuuuh yeah. Just step back and realize how excessive this is. I have no reason to believe that this zealous response would have happened without the blog post. Again, this is an emotional time. But we should be aware of this, and not make any rash decisions. Just talk. Change won't happen due to a sudden change forced from high horses. It happens gradually, by making everyone realize what the issue is. The problem isn't going anywhere, so let's just wait until everyone cools down and we can have an objective discussion. *Then* we can figure out what to do.

**tl;dr** The blog post was very unfortunate in my opinion. There is a problem, but now it's somehow all worse and we're all angry. Let's just talk before starting to shout at each other on main. Don't cause harm in an attempt to Do Things Right. Witch hunts are bad, Mkay?

Comment: I think we're on opposite sides of the debate, but no real concrete proposals have been suggested yet. So, if this is an appeal for calm, then yes, agreed. Interestingly, I'm seeing off-site proposals to help new users as a result of the blog post, so perhaps it is having some positive network effects.

Comment: @halfer, honest, very naive question: how do you see the "sides" in this debate? My problem with the blog-post is that I see it blurring and conflating issues in a way where I can't infer no sensible "sides" to it.

Comment: @yivi: I had that reaction when reading the blog post, and I thought the main question on which we've been discussing this made some good points - perhaps conflating beginners and excluded minorities would not work. I'm open to it, but it sounded rather broad. But it strikes me the sides are: folks who are open to co-operating with being more welcoming of new users, and folks who are not. That this appears in the midst of new culture war in the US probably does not help.

Comment: @halfer I object to the notion that there are just 2 sides to this debate; most of us would definitely agree on the fundamental points (everyone should be treated fairly and etc.), but the perceived issues and proposed solutions are definitely different.

Comment: Err, OK @ljedrz! Happy to hear your expansion on that, if you like.

Comment: Obnoxiously disrupting the site to Make a Point is not OK, no matter how strongly your feel about the Point or even what the Point is. I wouldn't even use kind entreaties like "let's talk and not shout at each other", but it's nice of you to do so. Feeling that you are indisputably in the right does not, in fact, make passive aggressive trolling OK. It's not like it's the only possibly outlet; there's plenty of meta discussions to participate in. So do so, and if you're getting impatient or frustrated, try taking a step back instead of trying to spread it around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @halfer. I asked because precisely I am all for inclusiveness and openness, both in language and in actions. And I'm also completely for quality control and strict (but kind) moderation. And while I believe most of the complaints we get at SO are for the latter; I still think that a lot more could and should be done for the former. Conflating "we are not giving equal opportunities to everyone" (which I agree with) with "let's try be kinder with users when moderating" (which I agree with, but do not believe is necessarily related to the other thing), confuses me a bit.

Comment: @Jeroen what are you referring to as "*Obnoxiously disrupting the site*"? I honestly don't understand.

Comment: @yivi: we are in excellent agreement!

Comment: If you want to take some action over this, it seems like the best option would be to simply withdraw your services and stop dealing with quality issues for a while. See what happens, see if the site gets polluted or if those trying to be a bit more kind are right. And if the former happens you can always clear it up later.

Comment: I would qualify the comment you quoted as trolling, and if anyone actually followed up on the actions it suggests ("let's all pile on flags and get them banned") I'd qualify it as disruptive. Admittedly, I wasn't actually part of the original discussion, so I may be unfairly judging it based on a lack of context. If that's the case, pretend I'm talking about a hypothetical crusade someone might be considering (and the hope that it says hypothetical).

Comment: For the record, [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366793/recourse-for-inappropriate-stack-overflow-chat-conversation#comment579951_366793) isn't a reaction to the blog post. Let's *not* conflate the two. I have [repeatedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365937/why-is-this-comment-not-considered-rude) [expressed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365878/how-to-handle-persistent-bullying) my evidently unpopular stance on snarky and potentially offensive material. The good news is I'm not entering a popularity contest.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, In that case, I invite you to flag the comment. Here's [the link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366793/recourse-for-inappropriate-stack-overflow-chat-conversation#comment579951_366793) to make it easier.

Comment: @halfer Carrying on with my tirade: Still, I can see how these two non-related issued might find common ground: How we moderate in general can have an impact, if only tangentially, in how inclusive we are on specific issues. And the other way around. A line I read in one of these posts (not remember if was Tim's or Shog's) about "positive externalities" -how sometimes doing something good for an specific group you ended up benefiting everybody- was particularly pertinent. I just believe that the way the blog-post presented things wasn't great, that's all..

Comment: @jpp I don't mind speaking up against questionable content.  That's how you solve problems. But taking excessive actions for some greater good is defeating the purpose of being inclusionary. That's pretty much my point here.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, Meta isn't a good forum to claim comments which have been upvoted 50+ times are rude/offensive. I have first-hand experience. If I find a comment I find rude / abusive, I'll flag. If you have any other alternatives, let me know.

Comment: @jpp: alright, now that I have the context I'm filing this away under "the usual Internet drama". I still have no idea if your comment was sincere or sarcastic, but I don't think it really matters, since 1) there's no obvious relation with the blog post and 2) there seems to a bunch of Personal Beef (tm) going on. There's not really any way anyone comes out of this smelling nice.

Comment: @jpp flagging something and gathering pitchforks on meta are two very different things.

Comment: That was interesting. Now can all the above comments be *moved to chat*, so it can be discussed what the rest of the post was about – and not just these final paragraphs?

Comment: Very well written IMO. 
I think it's best to avoid "please for sanity" as if the people who are in "the other camp" our insane. The people on the other camp have good intentions and I believe them when they say we have a problem. 

Note that when community members asked if we could "be nicer" in meta those requests were generally well received. I think this isn't a backlash at inclusivity at all - I think this is about parts of the community feeling isolated, attacked, confused and left out. It's just an unfortunate communications problem at this point if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: 'unfortunate' well, considering that I have been painted, along with the rest of SO as racist/sexist, that particular epithet is way down my list of appropriate adjectives to apply to that blog.  There is problem X, there is problem Y. there are other problems, there will always be problems, and trying to fix one will have a effect on the others.  All that can be done is to try and minimize the problems overall.

Comment: "I'd love to have a Stack Overflow where nobody gives a damn of who or what the other users are" you already mostly do. Sure there are isolated instances and they are immediately handled, as long as this is an open site it will always happen. Many users report never encountering any issues because of their gender https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366816/1398418 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309639/372935 a claim that it's widespread here is quite extraordinary and requires extraordinary evidence so far I have seen none.

Comment: @Oleg I don't have data and this is beside my point, but if the few-percent minority gets treated badly it can easily seem isolated. And much of the implicit pushback against minorities (in societies in general) is "acceptable" in each step, and only horrible when facing it each day. People using a hostile tone with you once, you shake it off. If you see that all day every day, you're being oppressed. This is not something we in the majority will see.

Comment: If you don't have data how do you know that a "few-percent minority gets treated badly"?

Comment: @Oleg I meant that the whole minority groups we're talking about amount to a few percent of SO users, as per the developer surveys. Any events against them will consequently be insignificant by volume. And yes, I believe most users are decent human beings and not part of the problem at all. Even less volume for the problematic cases, yet these will drive away the few percent. Hostility is always much more visible, especially for victims.

Comment: My position is that any hostility on SO that specifically targets minorities is extremely rare and has a completely negligible effect. So far I have seen zero contradicting evidence. Nothing good is going to come out of that blog post or your post that continue trying to claim(without any evidence) that it is an actual widespread problem.

Comment: @Oleg my point above is that we should talk first, take action later. I explained my own stance to put it in perspective. Discussing whether there's a problem should be done elsewhere.

Comment: My opinion here is that SO doesn't have a problem and certainly doesn't have the problems mentioned in that blog ... Community doesn't have to change and it is not suppose to change, hundreds and thousands of developers built this community, for newbies to join they should adapt to community (meaning do a fu***** research), community isn't suppose to adapt to newbies ...

Comment: The direction SO is heading lately is making me want to quit. It seems to be welcoming the flow of *Givez me the codez* users. Because (IMO) more users == more advertising revenue. Make the internet better has been sacrificed to the God of profit.

Comment: I had never seen examples of this social issue before so thanks for posting those. I feel like we should all just be calm. If the admins go full SJW or decide having a bunch of low quality posts is worth it to get more users, we can jump ship then. For now, lets just see what happens, could still be a publicity stunt and nothing will change.

Comment: This blog post seems to have created a divide in the community. Side one is looking for change. Side two is claiming there is nothing wrong. It would have been nice if Jay Hanlon had included some tangible statistic to support his claims. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow
Statistics
A 2013 study has found that 75% of users only ask one question. 
Is this statistic on the rise or it declining? Something to think about.

Comment: If the aim of the blog post were to spark discussion, they wouldn't have disabled comments.

Comment: If you think SO is unwelcoming, go visit Physics SE.

Comment: @TKK for what it's worth Tim explained their reasons for disabling comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366645/please-ask-if-there-is-a-problem-before-telling-us-there-is-a-problem/366690#366690).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Excuses.

Comment: " I'd love to have a Stack Overflow where nobody gives a damn about who or what the other users are." I just want to point out that this is an anonymous website. No one should even _know_ your ethnicity let alone care. *This* is what should be solved in a community such as SO.

Comment: @Jhawins like many other users I use my real name here. I see no reason not to do that. Many users use at least first names, or use photos in their avatars. These users will often implicitly broadcast their gender/race/etc. to the public. And yes, no one should care. But many still do.

Comment: The caption on the image doesn't quite help somehow...

Comment: @rogerdpack what do you mean? Help with what?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Why tho? Why do you need to use your name if it enables discrimination? I see no reason we couldn't all have generated but permanent names etc, if it would stop the discrimination?  Why not make everyone appear to be the same if they are to be treated the same.

Comment: For a minority they might say "Well I should be able to identify..." but to someone like me, I would be directly sacrificing my "male white privilege", I'm not going to fight to identify as that. . . . This post is absolutely serious and in no way a jab.

Comment: @Jhawins that seems like an XY problem. The idiomatic solution would be to educate the few users who make the life of others unnecessarily difficult. Plus despite the content-centric philosophy we are still real humans and like to identify ourselves as such. My hunch is that it would hurt you or me much less to "sacrifice our male white privilege" than how much it hurts a female programmer to use a non-identifiable name on SO (like many female programmers actually do).

Comment: My initial reaction to "How about No" caption was "you're saying you want to quell the negative feedback" not what I believe you were meaning, which is, "let's all calm down" FWIW :)

Comment: @rogerdpack ah, I see, thanks. I hope that's not a common misunderstanding; that bear is close to my heart and I'd hate to let them go :P

Comment: Or crop off the words.  Seems like this is a fun time to be on Meta... typically meta is a very unfriendly place to propose things...oh wait what am I saying noooo :)

Comment: @Jhawins you would be surprised about how many times on SE sites somebody tried to "explain" (read patronize) me about CS topics, because they wrongly assumed that I am a woman. That included topics in my own MSc thesis (pretty funny, I guess). So yeah, some users do (consciously or unconsciously) care about gender and they even get it wrong.

Comment: "the possible quality-control implications just make no sense" - Talk about missing the point.  Pedantic and overzealous rules-lawyering and "quality control" is part of the problem, not something to jump in the trenches and fight and die for.  It hurts _absolutely nothing_ to provide an answer to someone's low quality, off-topic, or redundant question _if it helps even one person learn and accomplish something_.  I originally came to SO to get and give help.  I stopped actively contributing because this site stopped being about that far too long ago.

Comment: @aroth ""quality control" is part of the problem, not something to jump in the trenches and fight and die for" - This is patently wrong. Quality control is why Stack Overflow is still a website.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto is that something you can link to? Sounds more likely that someone offered you knowledge and you are the one that assumed it was because of some other characteristic about you (i.e. gender). All genders, colors etc are patronized on SE. Is it _because_ of those traits or do the people possessing those traits make assumptions? I'm white and male, I've been patronized and overly explained to all my life as well.

Comment: It's one giant XY. Just trying to elude to that.

Comment: @Jhawins in some cases, I refer to people trying to contradict me after I stated technically correct facts on (for instance) NTFS reconstruction or other complex topics. *Usually* stating the same things again, providing sources and showing I know what I am talking about works. But not all the time. The same users did not show the same attitude to other users in the same thread/question. I would need to search a lot of past stuff to find specific examples right now, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I hear you. Its just that those sound like the same things all of us deal with. I have yet to see anything more than anecdotal evidence that someone was discriminated against based on these attributes.... It's surprising to me because there _surely_ are blatant cases of it on the network, but no one has brought a single case thus far to exemplify it.

Comment: @Jhawins surely you're aware how subtle these biases are. As I've noted before, there's usually no single point of resistance, only many little steps that push back against people. Those in various minorities will experience much more of that push-back (and in various aspects of their lives), which will lead to a hostile environment for them without leaving any obvious put-your-finger-on-it symptoms from outside.

Comment: We don't agree on the topic but I wouldn't expect us to. I am trying to better understand it tho

Comment: @Jhawins it's really hard because if I'm right, there's not much you or I can do to gain evidence beyond listening to others. I come from a country where there's a large minority and the majority of the majority is racist. I don't experience problems beyond the occasional remark equating the minority to criminals and scum. But the minority lives in this implicitly oppressing atmosphere (people grab their bags on the bus, policemen randomly pull you over all the time, etc.). It takes huge mental effort for them just to maintain their human dignity! This predates the fashion of being offended.

Comment: To most, I believe, it is not like post quality and moderation problems are mixed into minority groups handling problems, but the other way around.

Answer (score 36):

I'm going to humbly interpret this with what I've been thinking/seeing since the blog post went up, and likely condense the point(s) you're making here to something more laconic.

## Don't overreact to this.

Discussion is key and important.  Now's a good time and opportunity for dialog and less shouting and emotion-based rationality.  Let's capitalize on it while we can.

Comment: That statement of "Don't overreact to this" is so vague that you have to question how much value it adds?.

Comment: @JGallardo:  I'd make it more specific, but there's a lot of posts which kind of feel like they're overreacting to the blog post right now...

Comment: I'm sure the super large font and bold text are deliberately ironic..

Comment: But isn't discussion exactly what has been happening? Dialog *is* people are making their feelings known, talking with each other, and arguing about the post.

Comment: I'm still catching up to reality apparently. My views of Stack Overflow have always been that there was a problem of perceived unfriendliness. That was until Friday. Monday I came into work, opened Stack Overflow with that first cup of coffee of the week and saw a growing number of really emotional meta responses that started to talk about problems having to do with gender, race and background. Consider me really caught off-guard by this shift in problem domain, and therefore pretty stumped.

Comment: @geometrikal:  I still see a lot of overreaction.  Some are justifying what they have said in the past; some are blaming the quality of questions; some are blaming the volunteers; some are demanding statistics lest this whole thing remain a hoax.  Y'know...overreacting.

Answer (score -1):

**How About Yes**

Let me tell you a story.  I originally came to SO nearly 8 years ago, after relocating halfway around the world and accepting a job as an iOS app developer that someone was crazy (or desperate) enough to offer me even though I had exactly zero experience developing iOS apps.  I needed help figuring out how to do basically everything, and I needed it fast.  And luckily enough for me, the SO community delivered it in spades.

During the time I spent scouring SO looking for answers to any and every iOS-related question that popped into my head, I noticed that there were a lot of *other* questions on the site.  Questions about Java.  Questions about C.  Questions about concurrency and multithreading and memory-management.  Questions about what this or that cryptic error message actually meant.  Questions about things I actually knew and could answer.

So I started writing some answers.  It was fun, and it felt good to give back.  I was into it.  Really into it, even, investing a couple hours of time most nights of the week towards finding questions and contributing answers.  I marveled at how successfully SO had gamified Q&A, and how much of a rush it could be to get a sudden flood of +rep for penning a good answer, and at how happy I was to keep contributing answers even after hitting the daily rep cap because even if I'm not gaining points I'm still *helping people*.

**There is a Problem, and it's Here**

But then things began to change.  Meta went from being an esoteric little aside that was mostly ignored (and/or used to have fun discussions about quirky questions) to an *actual thing*.  Suddenly it wasn't enough for SO to be fun, or useful, or popular; SO needed to **be** something.  SO had a point to prove about how to make the "perfect" Q&A site.  SO had to show the world that by coming up with the right rules and enforcing them with authority, utopia was attainable.

Under the guidance of meta pathological behaviors like FGITW were ignored and even encouraged.  At the same time, benign things like comments were deemed pathological and a decision was made that "we're going to keep giving people a feature that says 'add a comment' against every question and answer, and we'll just yell at anyone who actually uses it and have mods delete their comments because comments are pathological and the commentators should know better".    Because rules, rules solve everything so intelligent UX be damned!

Users were actively encouraged not to help other users but to downvote, close, and delete their questions instead of just answering (or ignoring) and moving on.  Because that's how you build the perfect Q&A.  Such is the insular brilliance of meta.

And I really despise meta, by the way.  It's basically an echo chamber for rules lawyers and pedants to agree with each other and marginalize dissenting views.  It's a place where people with an overinflated sense of what SO "is" congregate to stroke each others' egos and refine their vision of what makes the perfect Q&A site.  Hell, just look at the OP.  "There's no problem here, carry on".

But I digress.  The point is, SO gradually became a much less fun, much less helpful, and a much less useful place.  I stopped actively contributing years ago because of this.

The blog post is at least a sign that maybe SE, as a company, finally understands that there's a problem.  It's mostly correct, and it's the first good news in all too long.

**Solving Problems and Learning Stuff**

I encourage everyone to think twice before jumping in the trenches to defend a bunch of overzealous rules pedantry that helps basically nothing and actively hinders people from *solving problems and learning stuff*.  I came here to solve problems and learn stuff.  And because I got in early enough, I was actually able to succeed at that goal.  And then I stayed to help others solve problems and learn stuff, because it *felt good* to do so.  SO wasn't on some ideological death-march in the name of "quality, quality, quality", and it was fine.  Better than fine, in fact; it was fun, and welcoming, even exciting at times.

SO doesn't need to prove anything to the world, it just needs to be a place where people who want help can get help, and people who want to give help can find people to help.  **Every answer that helps even one person learn something new or solve a practical programming problem is a quality answer**.  SO doesn't need rigorous quality control.  Promoting the great answers above the good is Google's job, and they do it very, very well.  Let Google do their job.

**Don't Shoot the Messenger**

And look, I don't want to come off too harshly here.  I'm eternally grateful for the help SO has given and continues to give me.  I still use the site often, even if I'm nowhere near as active as I once was.  SO isn't irredeemable, it isn't broken beyond repair.  But SO does have a problem.  And the problem *isn't* that someone *finally* made a blog post pointing out that SO has a problem.

Comment: _"And I really despise meta <...>"_ I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding of what Meta __is__ and __isn't__, aroth. I also think you're incorrect about several statements in regards to what rules we are enforcing / encouraging. As one who "despises meta", I wouldn't expect you to be up to speed with Meta's culture and inner workings. I don't think it's fair to discredit Meta like you're doing, in that case.

Comment: You can substitute "And I really despise what meta _has become_" if you like.  I know what meta was _meant_ to be.  Meta appeals more strongly to certain personality types than other; it doesn't attract a representative sample of the user-base, and has become quite insular as a result.  My current opinion of meta is based upon my experiences with it over the years, not on some arbitrary whim.

Comment: Users who come to meta and complain about the "oppressive" features of Stack Overflow are invariably unaware of the sheer amount of chaff that casual users can create.  On Stack Overflow, the problem is so bad that about 40% of questions that people attempt to ask never make it to the front page; they are blocked by software that was written specifically for this purpose.  This chaff can and will kill a site if you allow it to.

Comment: In addition, I dispute the notion that Stack Overflow is a *learning* site.  The hardest possible way to learn software development from scratch is by asking questions on Stack Overflow.  Askers who come to Stack Overflow are expected to already have a fundamental grounding in the basics of software development.  Very basic questions are a distraction; Stack Overflow caters to enthusiasts and professionals, not beginners.  Beginners should be reading books, taking classes and writing code.

Comment: What are you referring to by "*Hell, just look at the OP. "There's no problem here, carry on"*"? My question above? I can't read it in any other way. But then you are blatantly wrong about what my post is about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You can be a beginner and an enthusiast at the same time. The idea that very basic questions have no place here is techno-snobbery. If you can't bear me answering beginner questions because they are too easy according to some criteria in your mind, one of us is going to have to leave SO.

Comment: @JeremyP: [See here for a representative example.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366950/102937)  Think very carefully about whether or not you would like to see 50% or more of all questions asked on Stack Overflow's front page look like this.  Because before the automated question quality filter was put into place, *that's exactly how it was.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey You are conflating bad questions and beginner questions.

Comment: @JeremyP: There is a very strong correlation between the two.  Professionals and enthusiasts don't normally ask overtly bad questions because they have at least a passing awareness that you have to know *something* about what your asking a professional to answer in order to formulate a reasonable question in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They are still not the same thing. Stop conflating them. And, by the way, you should also assume the "primary benefit" that you get from the site is the same as the primary benefit that others get nor assume that your primary benefit overrides the primary benefit of others.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - Yes, precisely about your question.  The one in which you describe the blog post as "very unfortunate" and urge people "_not_ to take action along the lines of the real or perceived message of the blog post".  Even though the basic message of the blog post is simply 'be more welcoming'.  It _is_ a call to action, and a pretty benign one at that.  However you encourage people to ignore that call and replace it with (almost certainly go-nowhere) discussions on meta instead.  That's essentially saying "There is no problem, carry on" IMO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, these notions about what SO _is_ or _is not_ are quite entrenched.  I don't think they're useful.  SO is whatever its users want it to be.  And by "users" I mean "all of them", not just "the ones who eventually filter over to meta".  Though you're right, of course having a grounding in CS fundamentals is useful and it would be nigh impossible to acquire via SO alone.  But if you have that, you can _certainly_ use SO to help learn new aspects of the trade.  Does that make SO a "learning site"?  I don't think it matters.

Comment: And what does the automated question filter have to do with anything here?  I don't think there was any suggestion in the blog post that the automated question filter is the thing that's unwelcoming and in need of change.  It wasn't speaking to (or of) the filter.  The filter is what it is, and if it's removing a bunch of completely incoherent nonsense then good for it.  If anything, the fact that an effective automated filter exists is an argument for going easier on the manual moderation of things that _pass_ the filter.

Comment: @aroth thanks for clarifying. In that case ignore me. I'm not surprised you're displeased with meta; if reading my question you take away the message that I think there's no problem, there's nothing for you here. Putting your head in the ground and pointing fingers is a common strategy, but any change will only happen if you start actually listening to other people who might not share your beliefs in every way. You are very much part of the problem yourself.

Comment: Perhaps that's a fair point.  Or perhaps the unwillingness to look critically at what you've written and understand how a reasonable person could interpret it as I've done is the fairer point.  I'd suggest that the SO-like approach would be to identify and change the portions that are giving people the wrong idea (if you're truly _not_ encouraging people to ignore the blog post's call to action, of course).  Though it certainly _is_ easier to tell people that they're doing it wrong and are in the wrong place instead. P.S. "plea for sanity" and "bear graphic" don't  exactly help your case.

Comment: The first paragraph of the section titled "background" spells it out that I'm aware of the problem. There's a separate paragraph titled "what to do" that explains what we should do in my opinion, which is _talk_. The vast majority seem to have gotten my message. So I find your answer misrepresenting my stance as "*There's no problem here, carry on*" _very unfortunate_, yes, just like the blog post. I don't offend easily, I'm just sad.

Comment: Then again you may be onto something; I should've written "talk...and listen" :P

Comment: Ah, talk and listen.  As in, "do what meta always does (or purports to do)".  As in "carry on".  Or am I still parsing it wrong?  ;P

Comment: @JeremyP _You can be a beginner and an enthusiast at the same time._ Enthusiasm is a precondition for being helped -- if I don't care enough about my problem to make some effort to solve it, what motivation should someone else have to solve it for me? And after the answerer has invested effort in helping the non-enthusiastic, he is liable to turn around and not use the answer just as a result of general apathy; better to invest in those who are enthusiastic. OTOH a beginner who is enthusiastic is not going to remain a beginner for long -- he'll read the documentation from top to bottom, ...

Comment: @JeremyP ... try out various tests, Google various topics. A professional must also have some enthusiasm, otherwise he wouldn't have become a professional.

Comment: @JeremyP Even if we don't conflate _beginner_ and _bad_ questions, having 1000 questions about how to write a `for` loop makes it much harder to find the other more advanced questions, when the beginner's needs could have been answered by reading the documentation or easily gleaning the information from sources other than SO.

Comment: @ZevSpitz What do you mean **even** if we don't conflate. Why is conflating beginner and bad even considered? And I disagree with you about the difficulty of finding questions. For one thing many of the 1,000 questions will be closed as duplicates. Furthermore, there is this thing called Google which I use all the time and generally finds the question I want with very little noise. SO is either a Q and A site for programmers of all levels or it is a shrine for advanced programming. I'm here to help people of all abilities fix their programming problems not construct some bullshit ivory tower.