# Why was this question marked as spam or rude/abusive?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question

[This very poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098906/c-sharp-plase-help-me-finish-my-program) was asked, quickly downvoted by 11 people,  closed (including one CV from me) and then deleted with three votes. However, it has also since been marked as either spam or rude or abusive - why?

I'm happy it got closed, and think it's reasonable it was deleted too, but:

1. It's not spam - there are no links or products mentioned (not even in the raw source)
2. It's not rude or abusive - no name calling, bad language etc.

I am guessing it's because it was flagged by multiple users which caused this to happen automatically? If people are flagging posts like this as spam, either I've been doing things wrong or they need to be told it's not OK.

Image for those with <10k rep:

---

[image]

Comment: It *may* have been considered "abusive" due to it being a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097773/write-a-c-sharp-program-in-order-to-do-the-following) by another user who joined recently. Perhaps there were some behind-the-scenes shenanigans going on.

Comment: Dunno - maybe someone thouight it was rude an abusive to burn their old account, make a new one and post the same,bad question, which it seems is what happened?  If so, I would have thought a cutom mod flag for 'rule abuse' would have been more apt.  Anyway, it got closed and deleted.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, that's an option too. I actually custom mod flagged it myself, so perhaps a mod decided to apply that action too, though I would say that's the wrong thing to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were 9 flags on that question or its comments, one of which was a spam flag. When the question was deleted by a community vote of three members, that spam flag was validated along with most of the others.

I've cleared the spam flag to avoid future confusion here, deleted their puppet account, and put a few roadblocks in place to prevent them from creating new accounts for a little while.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. Is it worth mentioning to the user who spam flagged that this wasn't spam?

Comment: @DavidG - Hopefully, they'll notice the disputed flag. We unfortunately get a lot of misplaced spam flags like this on a daily basis, so we only message people about them if they become a trend or are targeting someone. Usually, we hope that declined flags are sufficiently educational.