# Was there an uptick in comment flags after the "be nicer" blog post?

Tags: discussion, support, comment-flags, statistics, welcoming

I'm curious - was there an uptick in the number of comment flags (especially rude/abusive flags) after the ["be more welcoming" blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change)?

If so, has this put additional stress on moderators? If so, what (if anything) can be done to relieve this? (Presumably, the answer would *not* include "quit flagging so many rude comments" - after all, that's one of the major concrete actions that the community can take in response to The Blog Post).

Comment: [Not overreacting to the blog post in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366920/1079354) would be useful to relieve anything...but we've had a few people pause what would be normal community moderation because they were worried that they weren't being nice enough in some capacity...

Comment: I am a little curious about why this is receiving downvotes. Ordinarily, Meta voting would indicate agreement or disagreement, but I'm really not proposing anything here.

Comment: I've seen several grossly off-topic questions this week with answers from 1-rep users that only got two close votes after an hour.  But surely that was a correlation designed to violate causality.  How many users quit over this is perhaps the more morbidly fascinating detail.  Remarkable how many users celebrate May 1st these days btw.

Comment: i spent less time on SO main shortly after (and ongoing), but it was less directly because of the blog post and more so because of the uptick in chat flags and the problems that said flags caused in chat.

Comment: [yes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368072/comments-asking-for-clarification-or-an-mcve-are-not-rude-abusive)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Spiked a little bit, yeah:

[image: comment flags per week]

That's comment flags per week. Note that they've been kinda high lately anyway.

Here's flags as a percentage of comments *created*:

[image: comment flags as a percentage of comments created, by week]

And here's *just* rude/abusive flags:

[image: comment rude/abusive flags as a percentage of comments created, by week]

Ah, now *there's* a nice spike!

Finally, an estimate of time spent handling flags each week (all types of flags):

[image: estimated time spent handling flags per week]

Comment: I like the spikes in the last graph, though. I can clearly correlate them to different incidents. :p

Comment: Can you get the graph 2 with the difference between the flag and when the comment was created less than n(maybe 4) weeks? Basically to see if the flaggers (flagers? flagel?) were just digging old comments.

Comment: Labor day and May 1st have spikes.  Users comment more when they have the day off, perhaps.

Comment: Well, you probably already know that *some* people were, @Braiam. Given we're talking about a difference of a few hundred comments over the course of a week, it's not likely there's a much larger trend hidden here.

Comment: Well, what I want to see if if people is more sensible to rude comments, ie. a ok-ish comment before the post is considered rude if posted now. And people digging old comments would hide that.

Comment: Yeah, age wouldn't tell you that, @Braiam. The queries I've seen have been mostly digging for stuff that clearly should've been deleted years ago but were overlooked, not borderline stuff. There's never a shortage of recent comments that *can* be flagged; the folks who are into flagging comments tend to blow through their allowances pretty fast and have for years.

Comment: The meaning of % graphs is unclear: where do they place the comments that are created in year X and flagged in year Y?

Comment: the use of a % value here is only to compensate somewhat for variations in overall activity on the site, @user4412195 - I could've used a ratio of posts or views or anything else that tracks with activity.

Comment: Where on the chart does it show the date that the blog post happened? Would be nice to see to understand the pre/post. If the whole thing is "post" then pre would be nice too.

Comment: @Hack-R the blog post was published 04/26, so, the last two dots on each graph are "post", everything else is "pre".

Comment: @HansPassant - To note, this is flagging activity. I would be more inclined to believe that the events shown in the graph (elections for example, or the increased ire at rudeness) result in more flags cast, not necessarily more rude or flag-worthy comments.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Many thanks, it's clear now. 2 data points isn't much to go on, but I guess you gotta look at what info you have. Of course the last dot is a *drop* in all of those metrics, probably due to incomplete data or something.

Comment: Data was incomplete for last week when I posted this, but flagging did fall off considerably from the previous week @Hack-R

Comment: With the y axis offset, even a 0.001% increase would look the same way.

Comment: I could've left the y axis off of that one entirely, @Peter - the actual % number is irrelevant, it's just a way to normalize the volume to make comparisons over time a bit less flaky (for instance, if the total volume of comments are increasing / decreasing then you'd somewhat expect a corresponding variation in flag volume). Some spikes are actually spikes, some diminish or disappear when normalized.