# Comments asking for clarification or an MCVE are not rude/abusive

Tags: discussion, flags, new-users, comment-flags, rude-or-abusive

This is the latest comment to be flagged in what is becoming a trend in faux rude/abusive flags.

[image]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I cannot see anything rude or abusive in this comment, in fact they use the word "Please".

Comments requesting more details, clarification or a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are not rude or abusive. In fact, that is what comments are for.

> ### [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated).

There's been a [decent upheaval](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming) in the community since Jay Hanlon's "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming" blog. We are questioning what we can do to make new users feel more welcome on the site. There has been a [spike in rude/abusive flags on comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367769/3956566).

There seems to be this backlash that any type of critique is rude or abusive. No it's not. It's vital for the site to sift through content and vet out poor quality posts. If someone takes the time to leave a comment (in a courteous manner) on how the post can be improved, it is not rude, nor is it unwelcoming. It's how the site works, we help each other improve the content, questions and answers.

Now if a user comments repeatedly under a post telling the poster what's wrong it can become counterproductive and isn't welcoming, it can become overwhelming. Likewise if someone insults or attacks someone, this is not acceptable. No one is saying that it's ok to harass people or abuse people. BUT it is OK to give constructive feedback under posts.

If someone is rude or abusive, or is badgering someone, by all means flag the comment.

People, generally don't like criticism, it's hard to take posts being downvoted, marked as duplicates, or someone telling us, it needs to be improved. But it's a requirement of posting on the site. The posts are critiqued, it's the nature of the voting and reputation system to float good content up with votes and remove poor content from the front page when it's downvoted. This is what makes the site useful for the programming community.

The way to minimise the possibility that someone will leave a comment like this is to study the help center and follow the guidelines.

The [Oxford Dictionary defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rude):

> rude - Offensively impolite or bad-mannered.

and

> abusive -
>   1. Extremely offensive and insulting.
>   2. Engaging in or characterized by habitual violence and cruelty.
>   3. Involving injustice or illegality.

Suggesting a link to read on how to improve the post, is none of these.

So please stop flagging these types of comments as rude or abusive.

Comment: In many ways this really needs to be expanded, as there's a plethora of inappropriate comment flags. People need to be able to take constructive feedback.

Comment: I wonder how many of those who flag constructive feedback are also paying attention to Meta. :/ Totally agreed, even though I don't quite know what more can be done to address this.

Comment: @E_net4 educating people about the boundaries of [how to use flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close). It becomes abuse of the flagging system (ah the irony)

Comment: While I entirely agree that a comment like this doesn't warrant a rude/abusive flag, it *could be* pointless noise worthy of a "no longer needed" flag, depending upon the context. Commenters sometimes demand MCVEs on non-debugging questions where there's no reason to provide one.

Comment: it's a vulnerability that we call "the anti-flag 2-way handshake"

Comment: @MarkAmery yes! I totally agree - sometimes these comments are not needed or a post is edited and they're not longer needed. Perhaps write an answer with this clarity?

Comment: Requesting an MCVE would be OK without the word "please", too. But when dealing with new users, I believe we should add that word. New users have enough to deal with. We can teach them that we don't really do "please", "thanks" etc once they have been eased in.

Comment: don't tell me this is the beginning of the *please and smiley face meme*.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I have a feeling there's some kind of litmus test in there... "is it still rude when you add 'please'"? It might be the test to distinguish between _rude_ and _direct_ .

Comment: Oh, that blog post is just... blaaah

Comment: @S.L.Barth well it's interesting, in many cultures it's rude not to use please and it does soften requests or suggestions so they don't sound like demands. I know I spent many years teaching my children to say please and thank you

Comment: @SurajRao _"We apologise for any inconvenience that voting down, closing and deletion of your question may have caused you, and we appreciate your understanding. Thanks for your cooperation, looking forward to hearing from you after 6 months of question block!"_

Comment: @S.L.Barth For new users I think it's more important to explain why they need to add a mcve than just simply adding please.

Comment: Telling someone he is wrong is rude per se. Never ever ask someone for information either, this implies he did not provide enough in the first place, which just can't be true as everyone is perfect, everyone is unique. It's just their personal style of asking. It#s not tieir faul we are no clairvoyants knowing what someone means. … Thank you for reading, please and welcome

Comment: @gnat flagging as rude. you forgot the smiley! :P

Comment: @AndréKool IMHO the words "minimal"+ "complete" + "verifiable" +"example" with a link to a nice page is enough for me to know why I should do that. We do not have to treat new visitors as babies.

Comment: @KarelG: Apparently there are enough who prefer to be.

Comment: @KarelG Unfortunatly I hardly ever see those words in the comment itself

Comment: @AndréKool I think S.L. Barth doesn't mean we must always add "please", but something very different: if a comment isn't fundamentally problematic once you add "please", it probably isn't fundamentally problematic in its original form either. On the other hand, "Please get lost, doofus" is problematic in spite of the "please".

Comment: @AndréKool yes, it is true that lots of people uses the abbreviation of it. There is a shortcut which autolinks the whole sentence as comment: `[mcve]`. But not many people is aware of that it seems.

Comment: You say *there's been a decent upheaval in the community since...* which is interesting. Do you have stats for that? Have we all been nicer? Has question quality suffered as a result?

Comment: @duplode Indeed, that's what I meant - the "please" is just a softener. But André Kool raises a good point - it helps a lot if we can explain to new uses _why_ they need to include an MCVE. I sometimes tell them, "help us to help you". We need to make it clear that including MCVE's and such, is in their own best interest.

Comment: @DavidG I think with "decent upheaval", she meant that there was a lot of heated debate, not that she had measured changes.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes and there's been an increase in [comment flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/was-there-an-uptick-in-comment-flags-after-the-be-nicer-blog-post?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @S.L.Barth You mean, besides all the reasons that are listed on the linked page? ;)

Comment: @S.L.Barth I was just hoping that someone had done some early analysis on question quality, wondering if our increased "niceness" has had any effect.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Touché! Then again, they only read that if they actually go to that page... and even there, the page is more focused on _how_ to make an MCVE than _why_ . Now let me flag your comment because it didn't start with "please", that invalidates the smiley :-)

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yeah, I saw that but it doesn't prove we were being nicer. On it's own it's a bit meaningless. One could conclude that more flags means we've been meaner right?

Comment: @YvetteColomb I removed the new-users tag because your post doesn't seem to have anything to do with new users.

Comment: @AndréKool I have rolled it back. "Please provide a MCVE" comments are very often directed to new users, and the broader discussion about how new users should be onboarded is relevant here.

Comment: @duplode Although I understand your reasoning I still think that tag doesn't belong here. First off all because like I said there is nothing in the post about new users, and I don't think it's a good idea to suggest only new users get these kind of comments (low rep/new user != bad question (lacking MCVE) AND high rep/experienced user != good question). For your point about the broader discussion I feel this isn't the right tag, maybe the welcoming tag should be used instead. Maybe we should leave it up to YvetteColomb to decide what tag to use and what intention she has with it.

Comment: Is this a question or an ultimatum? ;-)

Comment: IMHO, dupe-closing shouldn't be lumped in with other forms of close-voting, and dupe questions certainly shouldn't attract downvotes (unless it's a really obvious dupe that anyone could find in under a minute). If you add a bit of explanation in a comment to help the OP use the info at the dupe target it can make a world of difference. Since I started doing that I've been getting comments thanking me for solving their problem. It doesn't happen all the time, but it _does_ happen.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yep, as a site we need to clarify that a dupe is not necessarily bad, they assist search engines finding the result. I don't like seeing well answered dupes being deleted. I guess the issue is when there's hundreds of duplicates people feel the OP hasn't searched well and so they're not well received.

Comment: You know, seeing as how infrequent I see regulars use this exact sentence, and how often I do, makes me wonder...

Comment: @PasserBy wonder?

Comment: If I'm being flagged

Comment: @PasserBy it wasn't your comment, but suffice to say there's been many comments like that and with more detail asking for [mcve] or more details, being flagged as abusive.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Great point. There are a lot of rules, but without any explanation **why** those rules are necessary. (_otherwise the explanation is often hidden somewhere on meta, which is not easy to find_) . I often just say "to increase your chance of receiving an answer".

Comment: The `delphi` community sees this quite heavily. I mean in the sense of very poor questions that require improvement, or just closing, and sometimes deleting. As you can imagine, that also results in many comments trying to educate the OP and advise them to edit their question. And I see it all the time, people who react negatively and decide SO is not for them. For example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409314/building-complex-xml-in-delphi#comment101301608_57409314). In fact, OP's original comment is deleted, where they stated this is why SO is going under.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As someone who posts these links quite often under questions that are in severe need of a facelift, I *completely* concur. We've even graciously been given access to [shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) that make it easy to post comments like this. Just type "Please provide a [mcve]", and you're done.

This is *not* rude OR abusive. I'd even go so far as to say it is helpful.

**However.**

It *can* be seen as terse, or even condescending by some, mainly due to its brevity. A message that short would suggest that you, as a person, are not worth the commenter's time anymore beyond a terse one line directive (even if it does  begin with "please") and (possibly) a downvote.

I understand that users are expected to do their homework before posting, but not everyone does and that's just the reality of things. That doesn't necessarily imply that the user is not worth your time. Oftentimes they only need a *bit* more guidance, or a little more help in figuring out just how they can provide that minimal example. And it isn't always easy, depending on the tag or the software under discussion.

I've seen so many questions which were initially unclear or too broad, but based on some helpful comments from commenters, ended up becoming answerable, some even going onto become highly upvoted by many others.

To this end, I'd like to urge users who are kind enough to leave comments to preface your link to a MCVE with a little text. Understand OP's problem, what information is needed to solve their problem, and what is lacking. Explain what is required to make their question answerable. If you want to leave a comment, but don't want to invest time into writing it, feel free to use canned comments if you so wish. There are a lot of user scripts out there on StackApps that let you paste [meaningful canned comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) on posts. An example of a meaningful, helpful canned comment would look like:

> Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to be able to answer
>   your question, we would need to know more details about the error
>   you're facing so we can understand what the problem is. Please paste
>   the full traceback as text in your question, along with the *least*
>   amount of code and/or input needed to generate it. For more details,
>   see how to provide a [mcve]. You may also look at [ask] for tips on polishing your question.

How does this sound?

In the spirit of encouraging improvement, [as PM 2Ring wisely noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368072/comments-asking-for-clarification-or-an-mcve-are-not-rude-abusive?cb=1#comment591452_368112), it would be good to check back on users every now and then to see if they've made any progress toward improving their question. If you've instated a downvote or close vote, please consider reversing it and let OP know you appreciate their efforts.

At the same time, please also keep in mind that, while we want users to learn and improve, we cannot help and handhold everybody, it just isn't a tractable solution. If you find you're stuck in a situation where OP just isn't responsive enough to feedback and criticism, that's a good sign it's time to abort.

Comment: I agree with adding at least one example of what is missing or extraneous. It helps "prove" you read the question, which sometimes posters think we don't.

Comment: @Shepmaster While I don't fully disagree, I don't feel that I need to fully understand the question and all it's intricacies to see that it's missing an MCVE or an error message or some other crucial part and so on. I post a canned comment that lists all the things your post needs and move on. If they can't be bothered to read all the help that's available *or* my two sentence summarizing comment then perhaps they aren't ready to be helped on SO and should seek help elsewhere.

Comment: @JeffC Yes. All other things equal, if one cannot understand the question, that's usually because it _is_ missing the MCVE.

Comment: @JeffC Oh, I don't think you need to **fully** understand the post, either. However, if the comment has no details ("post a MCVE") **or** it's a rote list of things where some of them are already present, then I understand why someone would ignore that / become upset ("yeah, I *already* posted one, jeez").

Comment: *And it isn't always easy, depending on the tag or the software under discussion.* — A thing I'm starting to do is collect tag-specific MCVE guidance on the corresponding tag wiki page. A recent question ([Could we add a tag-specific MCVE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423)) is a feature request encouraging promoting this to be more prominent, but for now I just link to that info in my comments (when I remember).

Comment: @Shepmaster Do you think we need to write a custom message for each comment? (It sounds like that's what you are saying... just confirming). My canned message lists 3-4 things that need to be in each question (because I've noticed one or more from that list is missing in the question). I'm not sure I think it's worth my time to hand write an answer in many cases since the user didn't bother to read the instructions and include many core pieces to their question. Is it really too much to ask for them to review a list of only 4 things and provide some of the items they missed?

Comment: @JeffC I think it's not so binary. To state my position plainly (which I think agrees with cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ): "Please provide a [MCVE]" *should* be enough and is not rude. **However.** Based on my own anecdata, *tailoring comments to the specific post* has a higher success rate. I've only recently started using a commenting addon, but I make sure to fill in *something* specific when using it. One way of applying this to your example is to delete the things from your list that don't apply to the post in question.

Comment: I think the verbose message sometimes does more harm than good, it seems like a canned response. I tend to go for "Please provide a [mcve]. In particular, it would help for us to see your inputs A & B together with your desired output. Also, can you indicate what is wrong with your current solution?" It takes around 30 seconds extra to give the *specific* guidance, but it's well worth it. I often see some positive results from very poor initial questions.

Comment: @JeffC *I'm not sure I think it's worth my time* — when we get to the point of commenting, we've already decided to expend X amount of effort to attempt to communicate with the human on the other end of the line. For me, it's usually worth adding another X/10 of time to try and make sure the message is heard. When I don't feel like this, I downvote and move on.

Comment: @jpp wait, so, you don't approve of verbose messages, but then the example you provided is certainly verbose with respect to the example cited in the OP? Anyway, I suggest canned responses for people who are not willing to expend the effort to write a meaningful comment, but want to write a comment anyway. I am always one for personal messages if you can afford to do so.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, Let me put it this way. It *feels* like a load of small print copy-pasted from somewhere which legally is all well & good, but seldom *sinks in*. Neither of us have real data. I just get the sense when I started off I replied with the canned & got little improvement, but now get more responses by being specific. But again that's just a sense, we need controlled tests. Many people think the 30 seconds is not worth the effort, they are perfectly entitled to hold that view.

Comment: Hello! Please remove "_and welcome to Stack Overflow_", thank you.

Comment: @Cœur feel free to modify as appropriate to the situation.

Comment: Conversely, if you post a comment asking for a MCVE, _please_ check back to see if the OP has done so, especially if you also downvoted / closevoted due to lack of MCVE. Sure, a lot of the time the OP just abandons or deletes the question, but not always, especially if later commenters go to the trouble to explain why we need a MCVE. Or helps the OP to compose a MCVE by suggesting which sections of their program that need to go into a MCVE (although that mostly applies when the original question was a ginormous code dump of their complete program).

Comment: FWIW I always go for "Please provide a \[mcve\]" line, the reasoning being if the user wants more explanation, they'd ask. I did write specific stuff in there a long time ago, but didn't find it particularly successful. I also find the fluffy canned comment somewhat obnoxious.

Comment: "Please provide an [mcve]" is four words.  Your proposed comment has 80(!) words, but does not provide *any* more information. Its 20 times as long. In other words, it has 95% unneeded boilerplate. If a question (or answer) had 95% boilerplate, it would be downvoted and/or heavily edited. Why should comments be held to a different standard? Why should we go from a good signal-to-noise ratio to a whopping 1:20 (or worse) signal-to-noise ratio in comments?

Comment: On @Polygnome 's point, see also [this answer to a related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367861/2751851).

Comment: @Polygnome no please don't get me wrong. I suggest canned comments for those who want to comment but have no desire to spend time writing a personal, customised comment as per the situation. If you can spare a moment, please understand OP's problem and explain to them exactly what they need to do to fix their question.

Comment: @coldspeed I do not get your point. Both a canned and a customized response can be short and to the point and not completely overloaded with unnecessary fluff. We edit fluff *out* of questions/answers because its unneeded and just bloat.

Comment: @coldspeed You could easily shorten your comment to "Please paste the full traceback as text in your question, along with the least amount of code and/or input needed to generate it. For more details, see how to provide a [mcve]" and would not have lost any *content* at all, but have made it more *actionable* then just "Please provide an [mcve]". But even in that case, I have stripped 60% of your comment that is just fluff.

Comment: @Polygnome What you posted is _still_ better than "please post a [mcve]", which is my point. All I'm trying to say is you can still instruct OPs without sounding like an impersonal mechanical machine.

Comment: @coldspeed Curios, so you think being straight to the point is impersonal and sounds like a machine? I mostly feel the exact opposite, I always appreciate it when people give me information as compact as possible with as little fluff as possible... but I'm interested in getting stuff done, not socializing. And SO used to be about getting stuff done, that is why I am here at least.

Comment: Why don't we just add the "full traceback" (and possibly "example input/output") to the [mcve] page instead?

Answer (score 10):

Most of [coldspeed's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368112/10461681) is good, valuable and informative. However, I think much its content is based on a flawed premise. I do have one particular concern which I cover at the end.

While a large number of these flags seem to imply some people believe MCVE flags are rude/abusive, I really don't think that's the case. In fact the entire discussion here indicates there's pretty much universal agreement that even in their tersest form these comments are not rude/abusive.

---

@Yvette, your "question?" (*though I don't really see a question*), might have been better structured as asking: "Why are so many of these comments being flagged, and what can be done to reduce the false-flagging?"

As mentioned earlier, I believe coldspeed missed the mark. The problem comes down to the mechanics of the site. When a user asks a poor question typically 3 things start to happen:

- Down-votes
- Close-votes
- And comments

The user perceives themselves as being attacked on 3 fronts. And of those 3, the user has no "protection mechanism" except to flag comments. And regardless of whether any of the comments are rude/abusive, that's the user's perception; and they react defensively.

Now when the user sees a MCVE request alongside down/close votes, they might believe (often incorrectly) that the commenter also gave a negative vote. Furthermore, given that many people struggle to receive criticism (no matter how constructive), a comment that accurately highlights a flaw in their question may be seen as encouraging others to also down/close vote.

So the user, feeling trapped, lashes out by flagging comments. The biggest target will be any comments that *truly are* rude/abusive. But the next targets are requests for clarification/more information and even *very helpful* comments that are unrelated to the user's problem. (*I have seen a user rage-quit over a couple of down votes but net +ve score when: in addition to the answer to his problem, there were some comments pointing out other bugs in his code that he felt offended by.*)

The irony is that an up-tick in the flagging of MCVE comments might in fact suggest there's been a reduction in truly rude/abusive comments. It also hints at a possible 'off-the-wall' disruptive influencer approach to tackling the problem:
When a question is hit with negative votes and receives a MCVE request; have the system generate a mildly offensive comment that the user can flag and get deleted without any repercussions to anyone, but puts the user 'at-ease' about the site. (*Yes, this suggestion is a little tongue-in-cheek, but allegedly such subtle tricks to subconsciously influence people can be effective.*)

More to the point is that: as long as the site limits the defensive actions available when a user rightly/wrongly ***feels attacked***, they're more likely to engage in false-flagging. And the comments that are, shall we say "ranked lower on the user's *immediate gratification* bar", will be flagged more often. This is where some of coldspeed's answer might improve an MCVE request's position on the afore-mentioned bar. But that doesn't really solve the problem; it just moves the flagging to less "clear cut" but still acceptable comments. (*And **when**, NB not "if", but: **when** moderators make mistakes accepting false-flags they'll be fuelling antagonism against valuable contributors.*)

## Suggestion 1

As alluded to earlier, effectively the site itself is a contributor to the user *feeling* abused. There are 2 things the user is almost defenceless against; also the 2 that are usually the bigger contributors to *feeling* abused.

If the site offered the user an option to "flag" the negative voting, this should go a long way to reducing false-flags. But obviously the votes are ***not abusive*** no matter what the user may ***feel***. So these flags would have to be almost always ignored. (Like the VTC queue currently.) And I would argue that if the site were to *dishonestly create a **false** impression* that a user's concerns would be investigated, then it would be ***genuinely and egregiously*** abusive.

However, if that "flag" is used as an entry point to structured guidance, it becomes an opportunity to help the user improve their question and learn more about the site:

- It can be frustrating to see down votes, but people on this site want to help. They wouldn't be here otherwise. If you improve your question the votes will change. Did you know you can **edit** your question at any time.
- If someone asked you for information in the comments, please **edit** your question so that anyone trying to help has all the information needed to answer.
- Down votes can mean people don't understand your question. It can help to include a small paragraph with a background explanation.
- Sometimes users spend so much effort writing the question they forget to ask the actual question clearly enough. Does your question clearly explain what your problem is? Is your problem that: (1) The program doesn't compile. (2) The program compiles and runs, but does something wrong.

  - Doesn't compile: Have you shown the exact line the compiler complains about? Have you provided the exact error message?
  - Does something wrong:
  - Have you provided sample input?
  - Do you get an error message? What is it?
  - What happens? What do you expect to happen?

The prompts can even be slightly dynamic:

- Someone asked you for a MCVE. This is a very important step because without it people are forced to guess and that's not very helpful. *Do you know how to create a MCVE?* (with appropriate links/menus)
- Someone has suggested a possible duplicate to your question. Obviously the other question is not exactly the same as yours. But it is very likely that one of its answers will be helpful; and solve your problem much more quickly. If none of those answers help, you can **edit** your question to explain why your question is different.

## Suggestion 2

Add functionality to draw from a ***library*** of canned comments that have been curated. This somewhat overlaps with coldspeed's answer. I'd like to emphasise the importance of this being a ***library*** of comments. Current templates like `[mcve]` are woefully insufficient.

- Database questions usually require table structures and sample data.
- I've seen a geometry question that needed a simple picture.
- Some questions need input values, some don't.
- Many times MCVE is requested but user objects "I've provided my whole program." Sometimes with the addendum: "in a link". In these cases canned comments focusing on specific problems such as "not minimal" or "not verifiable" would be useful.

In addition, make the canned-comments fixed (like vote-to-close messages) so that there's zero chance of injecting something that could be deemed rude. This provides a guarantee that they're "safe" and it should not be possible to flag these comments as rude/abusive. But it should be possible to flag as "out of context". E.g. MCVE not required because question is answerable based on given error message. Or MCVE has since been provided.

I must point out that I do have a concern with this suggestion. As mentioned above it just provides a deflector for these specific comments. And users lashing out defensively would likely just find some normal comments to false-flag. We all know that moderators are human and not infallible. It's inevitable that they will occasionally incorrectly accept such false-flags. And this has its own negative consequences.

---

Finally, I mentioned I had a particular concern with coldspeed's answer.

> I'd like to urge users who are kind enough to leave comments to preface your link to a MCVE with a little text.

To be a little blunt. I'm not employed or paid by Stackoverflow. Any extra information I choose to include or exclude is my prerogative; dependent on my mood, available time, and assessment of the effort the questioner put into the original question. In fact, I consider the pedantic 15 char rule on the site that prevents `[mcve]` being an acceptable comment to be a problem. If I could simply submit `[mcve]` to indicate the MCVE is required, then if someone chooses to [bikeshed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding) the template with flowery insincere platitudes, they're welcome to do so without affecting me.

I'm happy to use curated comments, and there are many benefits to this. Whatever is determined as the "correct" comment for a given situation, it can easily be improved over time. So when it's used on newer question it may be more useful and of more benefit to future readers by linking to explanations: why MCVE is required, how to reduce irrelevant code, how to ensure it's verifiable etc.

Comment: I agree with a lot of your ideas and suggestions. Have a browse through my posts you will see some of my suggestions in the form of questions and answers. The "question" or point of this post was to try and direct people to flag appropriately and brainstorm for ideas. It also gives us a canonical link to show people. This type of post also encourages our longer term user base, as they often feel disenfranchised and need support. Thanks for such a well written answer. Nice to meet you.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Nice to meet you too. I've seen quite a few of your posts which is partly why I chose to answer. For the record, I'm one of those feeling disenfranchised, and watching to see if things improve. Though personally I fear the problems run much deeper than something tooling can solve. The "welcome campaign" is a case in point. It seems to me like a knee-jerk reaction in the wrong direction at the expense of one of the essential pillars to the success of SO.

Comment: In what way do you feel disenfranchised? What can I do to help?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Your offer is intriguing, but I fear my candour would not be _tolerated_. The last time I was open and honest: I received backlash, insults, abuse, and stonewalling (from someone who _should_ know better). It left me highly stressed and struggling to sleep for at least 3 days. My blood pressure spiked to almost 200/100. And for months, web searches finding SO pages would cause me anxiety. I haven't yet seen any improvement in culture that would allow me to feel safe. So I respectfully decline your offer.