# Mentor & encourage new users? Really?

Tags: discussion, welcoming

I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092258/how-best-to-use-javascript-to-print-out-words-in-a-new-window-or-application) on the review queues. I can clearly see that the question should be closed, but...

We've just been told that we should be nicer to new users. This post was by a newbie with a rep of 1 -- a new user. I don't want to close salvageable posts by new community members. I'd rather just ask them questions in the comments and massage the question into a good state.

So, I voted to not close it.

But apparently, I'm wrong. Despite assertions from the leadership-committee that we're not doing enough to help introduce people to the community, I've been slapped on my wrist for trying to do exactly that.

Where is the consistency? What should I do?

--
ps:
The slap on the wrist was a failed review audit.

Comment: use votes appropriately. Use comments to request clarification or suggest improvements. Use the tools available. Don't circumvent the quality controls and tools due to someone's rep.

Comment: By nicer, I don't think they meant drop *all* standards of questions. I think it was more pointed towards comments / interactions with new users. As it currently stands, that question *is* too broad, it might have been better if they at least had some sort of coded attempt.

Comment: How exactly did you get _"slapped on my wrist"_?

Comment: @AndréKool The question had already been closed a month ago. It looks like OP failed a review audit.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic thats also my guess but its not very clear from the question right now. If that is indeed the case the discussion should be about : _"Review audits need to be more welcoming!"_

Comment: Audits are based on decisions by community members, not SO employees that write crappy blog posts and never show up at the site.

Comment: Note that closing a question and massaging it into shape are not mutually exclusive. We have the ability to reopen. So close it (because it's not appropriate in the current state) and take all the time you need to make it better. Once done, vote to reopen.

Comment: @Bart I'd say that if you have all of the tools at your disposal to turn the question into an appropriate one, all on your own, and you want to do so, then just do it, don't vote to close.  Voting to close is there for if you aren't going to *immediately* fix whatever problems would merit closure (which, for the record, is typical.  It's pretty uncommon for a question to merit closure but to be salvageable by a reader on their own with the OP's input).

Comment: @Servy sure, if you can right there and then, fine. But the OP mentioned engaging in a back and forth in the comments. In that case going through a closed state may not be a bad thing depending on how quick and easily it is resolved.

Comment: Remember -- *downvotes and closevotes are not unwelcoming*.

Comment: Use your votes appropriately, but (optionally) leave a helpful comment to the OP, or at least never leave rude comments.

Comment: @user202729, *"down/close votes are not unwelcoming"*, well, we've heard dissenting voices in this regard from inside the company. And not the usual tech folks that are meta regulars, as Hans aptly put it, folks *"that never show up at the site"*.

Comment: This reads a lot like "being welcoming is someone else's problem -- we're fine as we are". I don't believe that someone wrote that closing and downvoting are not unwelcoming. I'm hoping that's a joke, but I can't tell.

Comment: @HansPassant if you have something to say about the blog post, post a question or answer. Stop littering the site with snarky comments about it.

Comment: @Yvette, please learn how to use and moderate meta.  The Q+A engine is not adapt at supporting the essentials of discussion, the back-and-forth that is necessary to conduct one cannot happen from the soap-boxes that are answers.  And please stop getting annoyed at my opinions, we already know that you don't like them.  You'll have to live with them, I already learned to live with yours.  It is not that hard, takes but to appreciate a basic level of respect for fellow human beings.  That you chose to chastise me instead of blindly deleting the comment, hey, that's progress.  Keep at it.

Comment: @HansPassant it's the reactions of other users. Honestly, as a mod, I'm remaining impartial to your comments and probably appreciate you more (ironically). I'm only saying something, due to the flags and other comments, maybe just try and be less sardonic. You do have a good wit, I grant you that. You know I copped it, not deleting one of your comments. We may not agree, but you're interesting and I actually do respect your opinions.

Comment: Inducing reactions is entirely the point of a discussion.  Everybody is free to agree or respond to a comment at meta, little stands in the way.  Some users might well ask you to suppress speech instead of making the effort to contribute to the discussion.  Hopefully you see that as a somewhat lazy and trumpian cop-out as well.

Comment: @HansPassant tbh I'm concerned with the state of flux, although I agree there could be some improvement in the site, it's becoming a little militant and it's important to maintain some balance. Believe it or not, I'm also trying to [achieve that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368072/comments-asking-for-clarification-or-an-mcve-are-not-rude-abusive). Also the bar in meta is different for the main site and probably that should be clarified somewhere prominent (again).

Comment: @HansPassant for the record, I don't delete any comments (apart from my own) under my own posts or that are in a dialogue with me, I also haven't deleted any of your comments, unless they've been flagged.  I wouldn't go and delete any of your comments here, as there's a conflict of interest. Even if they were flagged and were worthy of deletion, I'd leave it to another mod. We're quite strict on not handling flags that involve ourselves personally.

Answer (score 59):

## You should have closed the question.

The question is:

- Too broad ("is there a better way" or "is there a best way"-type questions tend to fall here *anyway*)
- Inspecific (what do they mean by "sloppy"?)
- Not likely to be of lasting value

The comments in the question were incredibly civil and polite, and went a way to explain to the OP that their question wasn't suitable for the site.

Being nice doesn't mean we change *what* we moderate on.  We can moderate questions and not be jerks about it, is all.

More importantly...

**If you think closing a question makes you a "jerk", I respectfully ask that you not participate in moderation any more.**  You'll be paralyzed by that stigma and you won't get anywhere with moderating or cleaning up bad questions.

Comment: If closing questions makes you a jerk I qualify for being a top jerk. I guess that fits, somehow ...

Comment: New feature request: rename "close votes" to "jerk votes".

Comment: @rene I agree with that assessment. But, in my eyes, that is unrelated to you closing questions ;). (I kid, I kid)

Comment: I'm still hungry after the sushi answer, so how about 'jerky votes'?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not worried about being a jerk -- I usually am. I'm just a little confused as to how to implement the 'be nice' standards without further guidance.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: Nothing has changed about *what* we moderate. It seems to be simpler to perform the moderation duties (downvoting, close voting) in silence instead of commenting on the question.

Comment: @makoto There are many people in the world, some of them get some sort of weird pleasure calling others jerks.  Honestly, there is always a balance in deciding to close a post or not.  Many questions are insta-close, some are salvable, and some are closed even when they are seen as clear and valid questions by others who can understand the question better than the closer.  Moderation is important, but not running off users is important too.  However, stating that not being aware of possibly being a jerk makes you a good moderator is dangerous talk.  We all should be aware if we "jerk" others.

Comment: @EdwinBuck One would rather educate users not to take curation personally. That is irrespective of how people behave towards each other. Name calling is not tolerated here. And this answer does not make the implication that you suggest at the end: "heavy handed moderation does not make you a jerk"; not "being a jerk contributes to good moderation".

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine Well, I agree fully that trying to please everyone is often a recipe for disaster.  As far as "education" accompanying closed items, Some do a better job than others in directing new users to educational links, and many new users aren't going to do their due diligence even with educational material.  I agree that not being a jerk contributes to good moderation, and my qualm is with the last statement "if you think closing a question makes you a jerk, [you shouldn't moderate]"  it has many possible meanings, the one here is benign, but it can be read as cancerous too.