# Should Stack Overflow users enforce a mandate or let the site evolve?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Meta is already full of debate about purpose, conduct and particulars of this or that.  In fact, I suppose many will initially interpret my question as a duplicate.  But my question is meant to be more fundamental than the other specifics that I could find.  If you read answers on META between the lines... or perhaps behind the lines... you may perceive the assumptions built in to most answers.  Sometimes it's subtle and other times rather explicit, but usually an answer leans on some assumption of how the Code of Conduct or the other "official" or long-standing guidelines should be interpreted or "enforced", but I have not really seen a good answer of whether it is really the mandate of users to actively influence others in an attempt to produce a particular culture, or if users should generally just go with the flow and let SO evolve with a less purposeful attitude.

Because I consider myself a direct person--an expert coder on some scale--my tendency is to want to maintain much of the old culture of SO, but also to pass that on in the style, attitude and details of my comments and answers.  For what it's worth, I think the recent update of the code of conduct is completely *compatible* with maintaining all of the other cultural aspects of SO (i.e. a place for professional and enthusiast coders).

Some may say "just use the voting feature", "don't add noise by actually commenting about guidelines".  But I can't help but notice a huge increase in not only the number of un-researched, tutorial-solicitation, give-me-the-code questions, but ALSO an *increase of users who simply dish out answers to (what I consider) low quality questions*.  Such users don't seem to care at all about encouraging or educating new users about the long-standing guidelines.  But before I turn this into another rant, my focus with this *example* is to simply point out that *I tend to have taken a mandate to keep SO in a certain way, and I wonder if I should abandon that notion.*  Should I instead simply let it evolve?  Should I just let such questions stand as is and "walk" past and shrug?

Focus!  I am not asking for psych advise about how to "let go" or how I personally should use the site.  My title question stands and I mean it as an objective question with a direct answer.  **Was the intention of the creators of Stack Exchange ever to have given its users a mandate to enforce a particular culture?  Has such a mandate changed or perhaps never existed in the first place, so that more of us long-term users should just let it evolve and abandon whatever mandate we think we might have had?**  Should we abandon any justification of trying to keep SO a certain way?  And let the new millions of users reshape it?

Comment: The mandate's been the same since SO's inception: to build a high quality repository of knowledge that can help programmers for the foreseeable future.  Thing is, though, this mandate isn't very well known to new users, and most just see SO as a help desk.  This leads to a massive disconnect between, "gimme teh codez" users and curators.

Comment: If we allow the mandate to fall by the wayside, it won't be long before SO becomes an equivalent site to Quora, Yahoo Answers, or Experts Exchange.  That mandate is why SO is such a success.

Comment: Evolve? Letting the content you describe ("huge increase in not only the number of un-researched, tutorial-solicitation, give-me-the-code questions, but ALSO an increase of users who simply dish out answers to (what I consider) low quality questions. Such users don't seem to care at all about encouraging or educating new users about the long-standing guidelines. ") slide sounds like devolution, not evolution.

Comment: This is a good question. Unfortunately, Meta users who disagree with posts tend to express their disagreement through downvoting; confusingly, it's unclear *why they think this is a bad discussion*. It's the kind that can shape communities. I also can't find a good duplicate for your specific question.

Comment: Might we observe that we – the caring *users* that check on and participate *in* Meta – can pretty much do what we want as long as it does not hurt Stack Exchange's income? An observation based on the (possibly imagined) notion that when we try to enforce stricter rules, The Company steps in with a binding veto. It has been said before that as far as SE, Inc. is concerned, more new eyes == more $$, never mind the quality of those eyes.

Comment: @fbueckert: If that is, indeed, the site's mandate then it's shockingly poorly explained by the tour ( https://stackoverflow.com/tour ) which explicitly, up front, describes it as about asking questions and getting answers.

Comment: @JackAidley The second sentence of the tour is "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming". I'd say "build[ing] a library" at the very least foreshadows the mandate.

Comment: @duplode: (pedantic: that's the third sentence). On the tour page it says (emphasis mine) "Stack Overflow is a **question and answer site** for professional and enthusiast programmers", "**Ask questions, get answers**, no distractions" and "**This site is all about getting answers.**" all centrally focused and near the front. My view, and the view that seems to be expressed here, is that acting as reference is a by-product of the primary goal of answering people's questions.

Comment: @JackAidley [1/2] (1) This is a question and answer site because content is presented in the form of question-and-answers combos. It would still be a question and answer site even if all of the questions were self-answered. (2) The items of the tour are focused on asker behaviour because the tour is primarily meant as actionable guidance to new posters. Note, for instance, the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" item, which concisely introduces, in the form of actionable guidance, the notion that not all questions are a good fit for the library.

Comment: @JackAidley [2/2] (3) If you excuse me some pedantry, "this site is all about getting answers" leaves it open *who* is getting the answers -- it may be the OP or a future visitor reading the Q&A. (4) I won't deny there is [a tension between individual and collective which is inherent to the Stack Overflow model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366956/content-rules-and-perceptions#comment581976_366956). The tension, however, is essential to what the site is, so we should learn to live with it, rather than "resolve" it by clinging to one pole and relegating the other to a "by-product".

Comment: @duplode The excerpt you've quoted leaves it open, but the heading "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" does not. It is the most prominent piece of text in the tour - the first thing most users will see, and perhaps the *only* thing some will bother to read before closing the tab - and strongly implies that helping askers is the primary function of the site and that this "build a library" malarky is secondary. The #SOreadytohelp Twitter hashtag conveyed the same message. *We* disagree with that, of course, and it's against SO's original vision, but the message is still clearly there.

Comment: @MarkAmery This awkwardness of "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" has to do with the tension I'm talking about -- the tension of using what ostensibly are transactions oriented towards individuals to stealthily build a collective work. I don't think I can explain away #SOreadytohelp in such a manner, though...

Comment: The true (effective) mandate is monetization. Anyone with half a brain should be able to see that by now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question, it's a rant (albeit a polite one)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty  Just because I have include some personalization in my attempt to explain the impetus behind it doesn't make the question a rant. Because the question itself involves the interpretation of the guidelines and purpose of SO, it will necessarily involved an element of bias.  I willing admit that I had adopted in my mind a mandate which I thought existed from the beginning, but now I doubted that was the intent.  I also hoped it would solicit some objective answers about how to interpret the guidelines and approach new questions.

Comment: @CPerkins Anyway this subject has been beaten to death.  I wish we could now bury it once and for all

Comment: @GeorgeJempty  If you think it has been beaten to death, it is because tensions have not been properly resolved.  I purposefully used the word "mandate" and "evolve" in an attempt to *refocus* the long-standing debates that others dance around.  Burying problems will not help if not properly understood.  SO needs a new moderation perspective, similar to its Code of Conduct revamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does our long term community need? What does our long term community need to feel valued?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373158/what-does-our-long-term-community-need-what-does-our-long-term-community-need-t)

Answer (score 100):

I don't think you realize just how much Stack Overflow's mandate, and by extension, all of Stack Exchange, has shaped the internet as a whole.

Ten years ago, finding help for programming was *painful*.  You'd spend hours upon *hours* trying to find a solution to your programming problem.  So much time was wasted trying to dig through old, obscure forum posts, only to find someone who had the same problem, and...nothing.  No response.  Or worse, they did get a response, and it was a link.  That no longer works.  So it's back to the drawing board, hunting.  Always hunting.

Stack Overflow changed that by offering a deceptively simple service; ask a question, get an answer.  Sounds just like a forum, right?  The difference was in the end goal: create a repository that would withstand the test of time.  No more dead links. No more hunting.  An Encyclopedia Britannica writ large, if you will, dedicated to nothing but programming. Making sure that which enters the library of knowledge is top-notch, won't fade, and available for whoever needs it.  Tending and maintaining the library of knowledge is a huge undertaking, however; knowledge continues to grow, and it keeps needing more and more work to handle the influx.

Experts flock to this system.  Some of it is gamification.  Some of it is a resonance with the mandate.  But it is successful; users feel an agency to help curate the library, to feel like they're making a difference.

But there's a clash between the curators, and new users.  Stack Overflow is a victim of its own success.  It is now the de-facto place to get help with programming.  Everyone knows this.  But these users also have no stake in the mandate, to make the internet a better place.  All they want is an answer to their problem.  So they clash with curators.

---

So there's some history for you.  Experts are drawn here because of the quality of the repository.  They stick around because they can make their own mark on that repository.  Low quality questions from new users conflicts directly with that goal.

If we stop curating, Stack Overflow becomes nothing more than a help desk.  Experts leave; there's no longer anything to do but help the never ending hordes.  New users stop coming, because there's no one to help them with their problems anymore.  Stack Overflow dies.

That mandate is *key*.  Quality *matters*.  Letting go of it relegates SO to the dustbins of history, along with the forums it was created to replace.

Comment: '*Ten years ago, finding help for programming was painful.*' - Actually, I felt this exact thing a couple of months ago when using an outdated that is no longer used and I turned to SO and found nothing useful because of how old the system was and honestly, I was lost at the beginning, no kidding, I was trudging through forums posts ranging from 2001-2008 (some maybe older) which jumped around in terms of the topic in a single thread. I'm glad and have come to adore the way SO works, no nonsense, no fluff, concise Q&A.

Comment: @Script47 https://xkcd.com/979/, basically?

Comment: @Patrice that relates 100%. :D

Comment: @Script47 I still encounter it.  Cost of doing business when your main language is VBA in Access.  So when I get SO results, they get clicked on first.

Comment: An old post with no response, or a broken link response, is not the worst. The worst is when they self-reply "never mind, I fixed it myself" and *then* years of silence.

Comment: Your last paragraph was a point I made in some other post somewhere, that I remember you totally disagreeing with.  There is a problem with SO and new users, it's perceived as hostile.

Comment: @DanRayson To cater to that perception would be to to allow quality to drop. I'm not willing to do that, and for the most part, neither are most of the curators, I believe.  We have a barrier to entry, and I'm totally fine with that.

Comment: Something your answer fails to capture is that it's not just between the curators and the low quality users anymore. SO has picked a side, and it's not with the curators.

Answer (score 69):

This summer, Shog9 posted an answer [which resonated with me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311901/175248).

> Water doesn't care what you want. No amount of pleading or nicely-worded signs are going to convince water to wet your parched plants when it wants to tear out a gully and carry away your precious topsoil. You can dam it, drain it, redirect it, slow it... But sooner or later, water always finds its level.

To that effect, no amount of pleading, signs or documentation is going to stop a user from posting a "give me teh codez" question, nor does it [stop users from providing an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354).

The only real thing we can do at this point is beg for the tools to start directing the water.  Better, more effective tools to help us moderate content - not necessarily increasing the number of votes, but increasing the impact of our actions.  The simple reality is that the water is coming, and the simple truth is that all of the most beautifully written prose in the world about what is and is not acceptable on the site is going to get ignored.

All of that to say:

## Our energy is better spent <s>asking for</s> demanding better tools.

Comment: I don't agree with this in its entirety. Yes, some users will never care about the community's norms, why they exist, or how to participate here in a way that makes the internet a better place for future readers - either because their desperation trumps such concerns, or just because they're sociopaths. But I am yet to be convinced one way or the other about what proportion of bad contributors fit into this category. I posit an alternative category: those who read the *deliberately crafted* copy that advertises the site as being primarily a place to come and ask for help, like the [1/3] ...

Comment: [2/3] examples mentioned in the comments on this question, then *take it seriously* and post a giant code dump here to be debugged exactly as we invited them to. I see new users all the time who clearly have a different vision to us of what the site is for and feel aggrieved when we act on *ours* - examples I come across frequently are users who are angry at my ingratitude when I downvote their wrong answer to my question since surely an attempt at help is better than nothing, or users who complain about me necroing old threads because the OP has moved on and won't benefit. As long as ...

Comment: [3/3] ... we've got copy around in prominent places that supports their vision, and as long as the company is pushing the "welcoming" drive, I will always have some sympathy for such users. The site *told* them they were welcome to come and seek help here, and then rebuffed them. Dismissing them as people who will never read or care about our rules does them an injustice; they're just people who were lied to about what we're here for.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  The "welcoming" drive has nothing to do with maintaining the quality of content on Stack Overflow.  One can be welcoming on the site and not act like a jerk when it comes to content moderation.  Those two things are thoroughly mutually exclusive.

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence of that reply. The welcoming drive *started* with a blog post containing, amongst many other things, a broad complaint that the very fact that we try to curate questions *at all* is unwelcoming: namely, the sentence *"Too often, someone comes here to ask a question, only to be told that they did it wrong."* Whatever discussion and official backpedalling has happened on Meta since then (where newbies will never see it), that post, rejecting the legitimacy of our choice not to embrace every question asked, remains the most public statement we've made.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  [I touch on this in a different Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368530/1079354).  Content moderation does not *also* incorporate commentation.  Being *told* they did it wrong implies that someone went out of their way to leave them a comment telling them that they did it wrong as opposed to the system telling them that they did it wrong.  If the system were telling people that they did it wrong, the angst would be directed more at the *system* instead of its curators.

Comment: Ugh. So your solution to users being upset at closure is to... deny them any meaningful explanation of why, or any human target to argue with, so that they can just rage into the void? You're not the first to suggest it, and I remain entirely opposed. Not only would it do harm to the quality of our content by denying users the chance to improve their posts or users wielding moderation powers to realise that they've made a mistake after being argued with, but it is pointlessly disrespectful and hostile to the user on the receiving end. Replacing [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] specific feedback from a human peer with generic chastisement by an uncaring machine is not an improvement in civility, and I don't really comprehend why anyone thinks otherwise. The rage that many people feel when a soulless computer (or, relatedly, a soulless bureaucracy) refuses to do something important to them is so established that it has become a comedy trope - and that a lack of human explanation is frequently cited as an *aggravating* factor when the media report on some corporate or government system wrongly refusing someone service. Why would we deliberately adopt that model?

Comment: @MarkAmery:  It reads to me like you're volunteering to be a punching bag for users to vent and hurl abuse at.  I simply ***refuse*** to be treated like one, and I don't want anyone else to be, but I certainly can't *stop* you.  The big thing here is that the system should be improved to guide users as opposed to requiring human feedback to explain why a person got their question wrong.   Additionally, it isn't like users are completely devoid of any way to get human feedback on their question.  They can ask a question on Meta about their SO question even without the requisite rep.

Comment: In any case, I'm not really sure how we veered on to this. How is the question of whether the system or a human being tells an asker what they did wrong have any relevance to the meaning of what I quoted from Jay's blog post, or to my assertion that the "welcoming" drive as originally presented is fundamentally opposed to question curation? Is your take that Jay was, like you, *only* complaining about human-written criticism, not machine-provided criticism, and that an ordinary reader would understand it that way? If so, then I find that implausible. If not, then I don't understand your point.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  The human-provided criticism is abundant, plentiful and will bite back when provoked in *just* the right way.  The machine-provided criticism is static and doesn't care how loudly you shout at it.  Both need to be improved, but it seems easier to delegate to the system more than to humans since consensus is hard to come by these days.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  We got on to this chiefly because you believe that being welcoming is tied to moderation.  It isn't, unless you feel like content moderation makes you a jerk in some way.  I'm comfortable with leaving it at us "agreeing to disagree" there.

Comment: @Makoto I think the welcoming initiative is tied to moderation in that the blog post makes it seem that any moderation whatsoever is considered unwelcoming.

Comment: That welcoming initiatives has certainly changed how I vote on questions. Before I might have left a very slightly snarky comment to point out to readers why a question is bad. But not now. Now I mercilessly down vote beginners questions  if they have even the slightest problem. Because I may do nothing else.

Comment: @Raedwald:  You're ironically proving both Mark's and my point.  I would also say that "beginner" questions are still welcome here as long as they're otherwise on-topic, so you're misapplying your votes.  Thanks for laying off of the snarkiness though; that actually *does* help.

Comment: @Makoto  So how are we supposed to demand better tools?  I've seen dozens of users over the years demand better tools, and over time SO's staff have been less and less willing to give them those tools.  Is there even a modern example of this working?  At this point all I see is radio silences and unfulfilled promises on even the most supported ideas for moderation tooling.

Comment: @opa:  Keep shouting.  If they keep ignoring us then the site's quality will suffer for it, which would be more on their heads than ours.

Comment: @opa I recommend to shout on Twitter. Public shamming seems to work, since they actively ignore meta feedback.

Comment: @Braiam I think that the SE employees just find people saying what they want to hear on Twitter and use that as an excuse.  All of the people on twitter telling them that they want quality standards and effective moderation get ignored just like they do on meta.

Comment: @Makoto The counter point to your answer is that things like SE's blog post, and their CoC changes, and other similar *non-technical* changes *have* encouraged at least some number of people to curate content less, to not use their moderation tools, and to just generally lower their quality standards.  Clearly people *can* be persuaded to act differently outside of any technical change to the system.  Obviously not everyone can change on every issue, but underestimating the power of just talking to people is dangerous.  *Both* better guidance *and* technical changes are needed.

Answer (score 7):

We can't tell you whether you should try to propagate what you feel is SO's mandate or not.  If you want to try to enforce quality standards, and encourage those around you to, are you really going to stop doing what you consider *a mandate* just because some meta user told you not to bother anymore, or even if SO the company told you to, for that matter?

Conversely, if you feel that trying to encourage others to act a certain way isn't a good use of your time, or that it's not your place to do it, you're not going to do it just because I tell you that you should.

People that want to propagate what they feel SO's core values are are free to do so, and they certainly aren't obligated to.  So really it just comes down to whether or not you think it's worthwhile.  We can't tell you that.

As for whether the creators of the site intended its users to be allowed to propagate the community's values to others, absolutely.  The whole design of the site is that it is *community moderated*, rather than moderated on high by the company itself.  The company has *some* influence, but only to a point.  As a direct consequence of that, the site, and its values, will change over time (and they have, sometimes significantly, sometimes not).  Some of the things mentioned as founding values very quickly came to be found to be problematic, new values have been found that weren't there.  This was expected from the start.  (Different people will have different opinions on *which* values are flexible, or which should or should not change, naturally.)

Comment: The last paragraph is really what I was soliciting.  I confess that I personalized the question... I even bolded the personalized part.  That is just the style I write with.  Frankly I know that there a lot of others who feel similarly, but I was *not asking for personal advice* and even said that.  The main question and the related question at the end are not personal.

Answer (score 5):

> whether it is really the mandate of users to actively influence others in an attempt to produce a particular culture, or if users should generally just go with the flow and let SO evolve with a less purposeful attitude.

How do you think the community will evolve without user interaction? If we "go with the flow" and let people do as they please, that will still produce a particular culture... and in my opinion, it will be problematic for several reasons:

- rules won't get enforced, so they'll become more like guidelines, and then more like opinions.
- users will ask duplicate questions, creating more waste on the site and on SO's servers
- comments won't get cleaned up, so we'll have to scroll and scroll and scroll just to get to the real content of a page
- off-topic questions won't get closed or deleted; the extreme resolution of this is that Stack Overflow will become the place to go for any kind of question, perhaps even ones not about electronics at all. We have already seen some blatantly off-topic questions here like 'how should I handle this fight with my boyfriend'; if active curation ceases... that includes enforcement of things like site topicality.
- tags won't be curated/cleaned, so we'll get ten different tags for the same thing, which will make searching for specific content (even) harder.

> Was the intention of the creators of Stack Exchange ever to have given its users a mandate to enforce a particular culture?

Yes, that's the point of community-elected moderators and a back-facing site called Meta.[SiteName]. A place to discuss things about that site while keeping said site clean and oriented toward its purpose.

> Has such a mandate changed or perhaps never existed in the first place, so that more of us long-term users should just let it evolve and abandon whatever mandate we think we might have had?

This is just a rephrasing of your previous question rephrased in a loaded way.

> Should we abandon any justification of trying to keep SO a certain way? And let the new millions of users reshape it?

Also a loaded question, and the answer is (hopefully obviously) no. Things tend toward entropy and chaos. If you stop introducing order into this system, then it will tend toward entropy and chaos; Stack Overflow will cease to be a nice/useful thing. To keep it nice, just like keeping a garden or lawn nice, requires constant effort and maintenance, not to mention course correction.

Comment: These points are presented as obvious, but cleaning tags and comments, flagging duplicates and apparently off-topic questions, and even voting... all those don't quite address many almost-okay-but-lazy questions that only a get a few votes (up or down), followed by an answer that guesses at a solution to the bad question which then gets accepted as the answer or perhaps a few token votes.  I have tried to "coach" new users (in an attempt to "be nicer") rather than just down voting, but that backfires when others post answers before the question is fixed. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] But now the question has an answer (sometimes reasonable and even useful), but the overall quality or usefulness is not there.  But moderators don't see it as extreme enough to delete it or put it on hold, so now another lingering low quality post that nobody will ever vote on again, nor waste time fixing.  But a question that will litter search results for future users.  So the overall understanding of a "mandate" and how to implement it while being nice and not starting comment flame wars, etc. is not well understood.  I think many are uncertain how to handle these cases.

Comment: @CPerkins The subject of your post is about users dictating a culture (e.g. a meta community) and whether there's a mandate for that, but these two comments of yours seem primarily concerned with directly interacting with new users/their content. These are two separate concerns: whether we have the 'authority' to determine how we want the site to evolve, and our ability/tooling to engage with new users.

Comment: I hope my question is applicable at all levels, and I did not intend it to apply only to the meta community, nor only to high-rep moderators.  I'm a relatively low-rep user with limited abilities, so my way of maintaining SO quality and applying guidelines has primarily been commenting and flagging low-quality posts of new users.  I was addressing your list of SO elements that would suffer if we "go with the flow" (and I don't disagree BTW), but I tried expressing (perhaps with a poor example) of how the tools don't really help if the mandate is not well understood by the community.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of increasing low quality posts has existed for the entire duration of Stack Overflow, it is just that at this scale, if all you look at is the sum of the material produced at the low quality percentage, then it may feel as though the amount of low quality is taking over because of its growth. It isn't, it is just growing at scale as well.

The site mandate has always been the same: quality content. There is definitely some interpretation involved in where to draw the line between quality and not quality, as well as where the topicality of content resides.

However, it is the content which shapes Stack Overflow. Some users have produced higher visible content than others, some have produced higher value content than others, but overall it is the content that shaped the site.

I am saying this because millions of new users cannot really reshape Stack Overflow except with quality content. They can carelessly create low visibility, low quality, low value content which ebbs into nothingness; and no matter the volume it will not reshape Stack Overflow.

If, somehow, these millions of new users all manage to come in and relentlessly pour high quality content into the site, then that would be the only way it would be possible for it to be reshaped. In that case...

[image]

Comment: It's a bit naive to dismiss observations of increasingly poor quality as "all in proportion" as though nothing changed.  But for a moment I'll consider that it's just scale. For an individual user who gives time and effort to contribute useful content, combing through new question... scale can be a terrible thing that destroys the entire experience.  As a single individual, I have no more patience and time to waste weeding out 100 of 1000 posts just because I may have done the same for 10 of 100 five years ago.  It doesn't work to just say "let others weed out the additional 90"!

Comment: @CPerkins - Perhaps it is naive of you, barely aware of meta and the revolving door question you just posed, to think that only now quality is "increasingly poor". What data do you have to support such a claim? How is your quandry here any different than the hundreds or thousands of posts from the past? Many of which I have answered, and to be honest, my patience is similarly waning from seeing such assertions with such an obvious lack of commitment to historical precedence or evidence. Being that you posed this with such strong conviction, why not have backed it up with actual research?

Comment: Revolving door?  No.  It was difficult to choose the words to avoid that perception, but I attempted in multiple ways to express that the question is meant to cut to the underlying issue that others dance around.  The large number of posts you mention that bother you indicate an apparent interest and/or unresolved theme.  Why do you not address the simple case I put forward in my comment?  Instead I get ad hominem backlash requiring me to be utter expert in SO history, data, meta, etc., in order to participate??  Sorry I said "naive", but it wasn't meant as a deep personal jab.

Comment: @CPerkins - To  be honest, your simple observations are flawed, as is the premise that follows from them. There is no data shown, nor facts referenced; there is no precedence cited, nor analysis presented. You pose the same question and exhibit the same behavior that you lament against with this un-researched question. The titular question of mandate is addressed in this answer. The rest of the fluff with regards to personal feelings of "increasingly poor quality" needs quantification and is not really worth addressing. As for my feelings, I disagree with your observation.

Comment: I apologized for the "naive" comment, but continue to just get attacks on me and the question. "Research" qualification are certainly different for meta discussion questions... this is not the main programming site.  I addressed in my first comment, then asked again why you don't address the issue of individual programmers. The behaviors, understanding, attitudes, time, effort and patience of **individual programmers** don't scale. Millions of new users can also reshape SO with low quality content, because it effects the participation of others who also handle high quality content.