# Are there any resilient data that the "new contributor" indicator helped to push site quality yet?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement, new-contributor-indicator

Much as the question title says.

I am not an SEDE crack enough to research about that myself. But my guts say that the recently introduced indicator didn't help much to improve the quality of questions or answers from new contributors.

Well, it might encourage and remind to play gently with them for experienced users, but regarding the point we're just moderating content rather than users it doesn't seem to help much.

Also it reminds not to put comments which might be considered rude by them, but that's somehow subjective from point of the *new user* anyways IMO.

Most of the *"veterans"* seem to just aim for the overall quality of the site, and just use the engine's mechanisms to judge that.

So my questions are:

1. **Is there any observable impact on quality due to introduction of the *New Contributor indicator*?**
2. **If not, why should we keep it?**

---

<sub>BTW: Happy Winter Bash everyone!</sub>

Comment: As suggested by Makoto, I would like to see whether there was an observable impact on the attitude of veteran users towards new contributors, and (especially) vice versa.

Comment: I don't think that the "new contributor" indicator was *ever* intended to increase site quality.

Comment: What do you mean by "resilient" data?

Comment: I never expected the new contributor indicator to improve site quality, but since it was part of the welcoming movement, and the welcoming movement has focused heavily on unwelcoming comments, I made a proposal on Meta SE about a way to see if the New Contributor indicator has helped push away unwelcoming content: [Let's use the Snark Detector to actually find out if the Contributor Indicator is having any effect where we want it to.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314563/363946)

Comment: Maybe you mean "robust data"? According to my dictionary, "resilient" is "1. (of a person or animal) able to withstand or recover quickly from difficult conditions. 2. (of a substance or object) able to recoil or spring back into shape after bending, stretching, or being compressed." I don't think that applies to data.

Comment: Or maybe... "concrete data", as opposed to "opinion" or "guesswork"?

Comment: That annoying banner does improve the site quality to some degree. Before, I occasionally commented on borderline bad question to give some hint. After that banner shown when I typing a comment, it's so annoying that I don't want to type anymore. So I just downvote and close vote then move on. The final effect is that more mediocre/borderline-bad question will be downvoted and closed more efficiently, and comments are only reserved to good questions.

Comment: What is a SEDE?

Comment: @Cid: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm just going to codify my comment as an answer instead.

The New Contributor label is not related to ***anything*** in regards to the quality of posts we get from new contributors.  It is a mechanism which was meant to remind users that these people are new to the site and we shouldn't presume that they know *everything* there is to successful participation here.

That said...

Even *with* that label, there's no meaningful data points that could be extracted to prove that a question is "better" with or without the label.  People may react to the questions differently (with an [acute aversion to taking appropriate moderation action on content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368530/1079354)), but that will never correlate to better quality.

Comment: That's a fair point and answers my doubts well, ty. I suspect it might even helped to lower _rude responses_ for VLQ posts at all. Taking into account that _site quality_ also includes _welcoming_ that feature probably did it's job.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  *Maybe*.  Depends on [who you ask.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/04/welcome-wagon-community-and-comments-on-stack-overflow/)

Comment: I am not that much a friend of the _feel being welcomed_ cuddly waggon, but well we have to keep it at a professional and neutral level, that's at least what I've learned the hard way here (and to some extend helps me to communicate professionally in my daily work at my job as well).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ exactly: this "new contributor" thing worked some way. I see way less snark, and more professional reactions (including from myself :)), but that shouldn't apply to new contributors only. If it went away now, I'd keep the same behaviour.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, agreed. We would have been learning with that to reduce _snark_.

Answer (score 12):

**How do you measure quality?**

The only measure any SEDE query will give you is changes in commenting, voting, closing and deletion patterns.

But do those numbers give real answer to your question?

I would say no. You are interested in knowing the real impact on question and answers quality and not effects of "let's be nice and welcoming" policies.

Comment: Well roared, lion. Fair point!

Comment: I mean you can do sentiment analysis on comment replies, or look at following contributions.