# Since the introduction of the New Contributor Indicator, did the rate of auto-flagged comments go down significantly for new contributors?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement, new-contributor-indicator

In [August 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator), the "New Contributor Indicator" was introduced in order to help new users have better experiences.

The [Unfriendly Robot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393653/did-stack-exchange-cut-the-number-of-negative-comments-nearly-in-half-between-th) is an automatic system maintained by Stack Overflow to detect unwelcoming comments. It is used to direct moderator attention but also to measure the number of unwelcoming comments.

I wonder how the rate of comments made to questions or answers of new contributors that are detected by the Unfriendly Robot developed after the introduction of the New Contributor Indicator?

Deleting unwelcoming comments to a larger degree or faster is also helpful but maybe the Indicator itself had a decisive effect there in preventing these comments from being made in the first place.

There are two questions here already about the Indicator [Are there any resilient data that the “new contributor” indicator helped to push site quality yet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377966/are-there-any-resilient-data-that-the-new-contributor-indicator-helped-to-push) as well as [Can we statistically detect changes in friendliness from the Welcome Wagon, new CoC, New Contributor Indicator, etc?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373185/can-we-statistically-detect-changes-in-friendliness-from-the-welcome-wagon-new) but both ask for more general impacts of the Indicator and are more than a year old and I would be interested in seeing the newest data with the recently improved Unfriendly Robot too, that wasn't available in 2018.

Comment: I made a similar request a year and a half ago when the indicator was introduced -- Wow it's been a while. [Let's use the Snark Detector to actually find out if the Contributor Indicator is having any effect where we want it to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314563/363946)

Comment: Personally, I don't even consciously notice the indicator most of the time any more. It just fades into all the other background noise of the site.

Comment: I notice it. And I've intentionally adjusted my response on a couple occasions.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  But I would like to see numbers.

Comment: I notice it sometimes. It should have an effect but maybe the effect is so weak it would not be detectable anyway.