# Is it reasonable to suggest that people asking questions should debug their programs?

Tags: discussion

At this question

[Find, copy & paste specific parts of text from TMemo to other controls (like TEdit) based on some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637267/find-copy-paste-specific-parts-of-text-from-tmemo-to-other-controls-like-ted)

I suggested in a comment that the asker should debug their program which was not behaving as expected. This comment was removed.

It is my experience from answering many questions here that any programmers don't know what debugging is. Is it unreasonable to suggest that askers should debug their programs?

Oftentimes askers will ignore such suggestions. But a great many times I have seen askers debug their program and with a little help been able to work out what their problem is, and learn a new skill. And it is the latter that is always my goal when I suggest that askers debug.

It would greatly disappoint me if this site changed so that it became impossible to encourage and guide programmers to learn to vital new skills

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable IMO.

Comment: I'm embarrassed that this is even a question.   If a user cannot debug, they cannot develop computer programs and should stop trying to outsource the hard bits to SO.  There's a reason that skilled and experienced developers are paid well, and its got nothing to do with writing code.

Comment: I *imagine* that *one possible cause* of this outcome was the OP reading your comment and flagging it (with any flag option). Since the flag confirms they've read the comment, the comment no longer needs to exist, and so a moderator *might have* deleted it just to avoid an argument in the comments or elsewhere (and not because the comment was in any way wrong).

Comment: @Kevin Comments are for all readers of the post. Including potential answerers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "Learn to debug" doesn't tell potential answerers anything they cannot already see just by reading the question. They *know* it's a "please debug my code" question. It's just that some of them apparently don't care.

Comment: @kevin That's not so much my point. Leaving the comment there means that the next visitor doesn't ask again, and so on.

Comment: [You can find information about debugging, the role it has in asking good questions, and links to how to debug in many IDEs here.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have see "use a debugger" comment that was good and constructive but I've also seen such comments worded in a way that was obviously unfriendly. As the comment was removed, we can't know the exact wording. Could it be that a mod considered your wording "unfriendly"? If you recall the wording it may be a good idea to add it to the question.

Comment: @4386427 I can't remember the exact wording but I don't consider it to have been unfriendly. I requested that the asker include the findings of their debugging efforts in the question text.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's fine to ask people to debug their programs. However, one can phrase the comment in such a way that makes your intent is to help the OP if they don't already know how to debug. For instance, in the JavaScript-in-a-browser world, I often leave a comment along the lines of:

> Please note that often these kinds of issues are easier to identify
>   and solve through the use of the debugging tools provided by most
>   modern browsers. If you're not familiar with them the answers to the
>   questions [How can I debug my JavaScript
>   Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988363) and [Javascript Debugging
>   line by line using Google
>   Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10638059) (if you're using Chrome)
>   are particularly helpful to getting started. Debugging is vital tool to learn in the world of programming.

A bit more "welcoming" than "Learn how to debug, please" and points toward resources to get them started. I don't know what language the original question was in, but I'm sure there are sites out there introducing the idea fo debugging that language somewhere on the internet. And if not? Sounds like a great weekend project...

Comment: I created and answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) specifically to have a post to introduce novices to debuggers.

Comment: The first question you are linking to has been closed as  *too broad*.

Comment: @Raedwald While your question is great for most general debugging purposes (added to bookmarks), I prefer to find resources that are as close to the topic as possible. Debugging JavaScript in the browser is generally a lot easier than most other debugging experiences -- no external IDE, no need to attach to the program, no worries about debug symbols (except in cases of transpiled code and source maps), etc.. And while I link to a closed question, it is not deleted and therefore can continue to provide useful guidance.

Comment: Closed questions that have not been locked could be deleted at any time.

Comment: Directing new users to a closed question could encourage them to post similarly unsuitable questions.

Answer (score -12):

The *spirit* of the comment is to encourage an end user to debug their program to see what's going on.

The *message* delivered by the comment is one that comes across as cutting or sardonic; if they *knew* how to debug their code they probably wouldn't be asking.

The struggle that we face is that [we already don't support people who *can't* debug their code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364282/1079354), but asking an end user to "just" debug their code comes across as harsher than we want it to be.

So...in this case, I'd recommend that you not comment to that effect.  If you think the question is bad, just downvote it.  Wringing our hands over whether or not someone has or has not tried to debug their code is no longer a good use of energy.

Comment: We should at least incent those people what they can do with debugging their code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't necessarily disagree.  I'm merely framing the position from what the new policies seem to be at this point.

Comment: I cannot see how is "being nice" policy in contradiction with suggesting debugging as step toward solution?

Comment: Oh, I'm not defending the logic here @DalijaPrasnikar.  I'm merely framing the position from what the new policies seem to be at this point.  I do agree that asking someone to debug your code is a reasonable ask, but I've personally never been able to make that sound "nice" without it coming across as me with all of my rep stating, "Hey, why aren't you debugging your code?"  I'd rather users debugged their code before asking a question here - no doubt - but I've never come across a message asking someone to do that that *felt* welcoming enough to slide.

Comment: @Makoto Actually, it all boils down to "be nice" is poor choice of words. We should not be nice, but professional. Nice raises unreasonable expectations.

Comment: I don't disagree with you @DalijaPrasnikar.  It's professional to ask someone to attach a debugger to their code to see what's going on.  Unfortunately...I don't think many others see this site as a "professional" environment these days.

Comment: @Makato I wonder what the future of this site is in the light of all the changes designed to make it harder to elevate and curate quality content

Comment: This response - and any comments below it that are in general agreement - are making a far more negative assessment of the site than is reasonable. There isn't a ban on asking people to try debugging, and it is perfectly possible to word debugging suggestions in a positive and encouraging way.

Comment: @halfer No, there is no "comment" ban, but there is increased number of flagging comments suggesting improvements to the question or similar (suggestions to debug, read documentation...) While it is certainly possible to phrase suggestions to sound more positive at the end there is no guarantee that even polite message will not be targeted. I would say that situation escalated to absurdity and it leaves bad experience all around for both new and experienced users [Comments asking for clarification or an MCVE are not rude/abusive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368072/4267244)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: are you basing your observation on experience, or is there some data available for this phenomenon? Even if we thought that SO has gone too far in the niceness project (and broadly I do not), it is still moderators who are responding to these flags (and many mods are happy to be openly critical of changes to SO policy they do not like).

Comment: @halfer I don't have hard numbers just experience. I have been frequently browsing through meta questions and before "welcoming" policy was introduced there has been zero to none questions about why some "suggestion comment" were removed. Now such comments get removed more often (I have seen some of them vanish) and there is number of questions on meta asking for clarification. Linked meta question gives some insights from moderator's perspective.

Comment: While my experience is subjective and involves my feelings, being welcoming policy was also brought here by people's feelings. So expecting that one side can have feelings and other cannot is unrealistic. And to explicitly state my feelings, yes I feel like I have to bend backwards in order to comment and not accidentally hurt anyone and I am more reluctant to leave comments on questions than before.

Comment: Just to make it clear... my feelings are not a problem for me... but my reluctance to give feedback and just down voting and/or close voting gives even worse experience to people that should actually benefit from "being welcoming" policy. Removing comments like in this case will only backfire in the long (and short) run.

Comment: I mean this as constructive food for thought @DalijaPrasnikar: could your opposition to the Welcoming policy subconsciously be causing you to look for problems you think it causes? The inverse could be true of me: I am generally OK with the Welcoming project, and I have barely modified my advice on debugging questions (other than checking and softening my accidentally sharp tone).

Comment: @halfer I would not rule anything out. But am I trying to be as objective in my observations as possible. Problem with welcoming policy is not policy as such (and I don't object that) but the fact that it was brought as solution to misdiagnosed problem. On top of that initial blog post [Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) was downright insulting.

Comment: I appreciate you examining your biases @Dalija - we all have 'em.

Comment: (I understand why people say they are insulted based on the ideas in that post - however I think the problem is that people are not comfortable with the idea they may be subconsciously discriminatory. I think it is Science, but to the offended, it's just Political Ideology. It was brave to post that piece, but perhaps given the history of Meta, maybe it was overly optimistic to think it would be welcomed with open arms).

Comment: Since the problem was misdiagnosed, I expected from the very beginning that solution will not be the right one, since moderating content is still and will be fundamental to the site. There is no welcoming and nice way to moderate content. And the receiving party will always be unsatisfied by the level of "niceness" As result people are flagging comments all around.

Comment: (I seem to remember that it was suggested that we go easy on editing in order to be more welcoming, and I remember that I disagreed with that at the time. But I felt the piece was merely throwing ideas around to encourage folks on Twitter to get involved in the conversation in a productive way, rather than constantly sniping from outside of the community. Putting ideas on the table doesn't mean they'll get done `;-)`).

Comment: Incidentally, if anyone wants an interesting (long) read about the dilemmas of trying to do the right thing, [read this](https://charity.wtf/2018/03/10/post-mortem-feminist-advice-meltdown-march-2nd/). I think it is brilliant, and it outlines the difficulty of changing behaviours in a community, keeping it practical, and sifting useful voices out of the clamour of the outrage mob. It's a complex problem, to be sure (both here and there).

Comment: @halfer My experience is that in recent times (starting maybe 3-6 months ago), I have noticed comments I post being removed at a significantly greater frequency than before. Of course, I have no data, because there is no record of deleted comments available for non-diamond mods.

Comment: That's interesting, @DavidHeffernan. I wonder if the Community Team would be willing to release some stats on this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the site is testing new auto flagging - looking for unkind comments. As a result, most of them are not unkind, but actually no longer needed and just being routinely deleted by mods when handling the flags. Well that's what I was doing as a mod. But on a break right now.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thanks. I have to say that I find it harder and harder to become motivated to spend time on SO these days. I appreciate that we need to moderate unkind and rude comments, but it definitely feels to me that we have gone too far in the direction of hindering experts giving advice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've posted these comments in the mod chatroom and pinged Shog. It's something we should address as a team.

Comment: Thanks @Yvette: you are looking after us `:=)`