# Unable to post question due to large number of characters

Tags: support, asking-questions, error-message, quality-filter, character-limit

I am trying to ask a question about HTML and [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). It requires HTML code to fully understand the issue, but the problem is that whenever I try to post it this message appears saying that you cannot post this because you have exceeded the limit of characters.

[image: Question input field when asking question on Stack Overflow outlined in red with error messages: "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 41835." and "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."]

What should I do?

Comment: You need to limit the code to a very short snippet.

Comment: Does your question really need *all* of that code? A key part of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the "minimal" part.

Comment: If you cannot ask your question with a sensible amount of code, it is probably not suitable for the site.

Comment: @SOF Your question **must be** self-contained. If your question is not essentially complete with *only* the information that's in the question, then it is off-topic and should be/will be closed. You can have links for additional context, but they are not considered when evaluating the question for topicality. The point of the errors you're seeing is that the amount of code you are trying to include is **too much**. It's *very* rare for an issue to **need** more code than can fit in a question. It is *your* responsibility to reduce the code to a more reasonable size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: [A wall of code is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a free code-debugging service. If you're not able to reduce the code *at all*, you probably need to do [more debugging](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) and perhaps [more research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) before you post the question. There's no shame in that, it just means that you're probably not ready to post a Stack Overflow question yet.

Comment: I don't know why @nbk got so many downvotes and I am sorry @nbk that you got so my downvote due to me. The code that I was going to post was not mine as some of my friends pointed out Second it was necessary to use full code because my problem was not the `HTML` but `Xpath`. I only asked how can I post the full code so someone can help me to understand the error that I was making in the `XPath` expression. My goal was not to break StackOverflow rules and regulations by any means. If someone is hurt by my question then I apologize for that. @khelwood @Makyen

Comment: @SOF that doesn't matter, i told often the "truth" and got more downvotes than that, but it is still early :D

Comment: @SOF Voting on any of the child meta sites, such as here on Meta Stack Overflow, is different than on main sites. On child meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. Voting on child meta sites doesn't affect reputation. So, while there are some tangible effects for the post author of voting on answers on child meta sites (some badges), most people don't care all that much about those tangible effects.

Comment: Even though there's very little tangible effect from voting on child meta sites, it's still not pleasant to get downvotes for most people. We're social creatures by both nature and nurture. Just having people express disapproval of us or our works is something which most people find unpleasant to varying degrees. That, however, shouldn't prevent other people from voting, as voting is a *critical* part of how the sites work. Without voting, we'd have no way to gauge how good/useful a post is (main and meta sites) or how much agreement/disagreement there is with a position (meta sites).

Answer (score -39, accepted):

One way is to limit the code as suggested, to the parts that show the problem.

If the rest of the code is needed you can always add the code to [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) and post the link in the question.

But the link **alone** is **not** enough to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Most people seem to have forgotten their beginnings at computer science.

Not everyone is a genius and has to start somewhere.

They get a tutorial and start, but as they still struggle with the basics and they haven't learned how to debug their code.

So it is no wonder that they also struggle to find bugs and even to find the cause in the whole of their source. They also have usually trouble to explain themselves or to minimize their code to the essentials necessary.

In such a case they should post their error code and some of their code, but what if they fear missing something, so the solution here presented to add all or more of the source code on sides that specialize in that, is a very good solution, if someone wants to help. So if they missed some vital part, the helper can get it.

Comment: Re your edit, I would expect you to know by now that Stack Overflow is trying to help future visitors, not the one stuck beginnger who asks the question.

Comment: yes that is why the answer is helpful, as te asker demonstrates, that there are people out there that need more guidance, which they get from me.

Comment: One of the side benefits of a MRE is that it actually teaches you debugging skills, by forcing you to figure out which part of the program is producing the error. If anything, that's more useful for beginners than digging through their code for them and spoon-feeding them a solution.

Comment: that is exactly what  i wrote, to reduce as best he can, and  upload the rest to a a source code side, if something is missing, the helper can look there, what i don't get what you read i my answer, so that it gets downvoted. besides nobody can expect that newcomers can do everything perfect

Comment: Dear @pppery you are saying the truth I am a beginner with StackOverflow and @nbk was not trying to spoon-feed me he only told me how to post snippets of the code and post the full code on Github so someone can help me with the `Xpath` Expression that was complex and wasn't working on that specific `HTML` code. If i only posted the small parts of `HTML` code then no one would be able to understand the problem but @nbk only showed me how to use StackOverflow and GitHub so that I don't pass the code limit and stand within the boundaries of StackOverflow rules and regulation. Thanks @nbk for help

Comment: One of the better received proposals is *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*.

Answer (score 28):

To counter nbk's answer, links to GitHub or Pastebin would be absolutely fine if this were mainly a help site where the goal was to give personal help to the original poster, but it's not; rather it is a question and answer site where the goal is to provide useful questions and answers that help future visitors with similar problems. And while the OP often receives help, again, this is not the primary purpose but rather a wonderful by-product of fulfilling this site's purpose.

Specifically:

- Links often go dead, and so they can't be trusted to hold key information that is necessary for future visitors to fully understand the question
- Links to code repositories can hold vast quantities of code, allowing the code that is contributing to the problem to be buried in the haystack, making questions less answerable and less useful.

Instead, it is incumbent on the original poster to cull the code down to the bare minimum required to allow others to reproduce the problem. This may require a large amount of work on the part of the OP, but this is quite appropriate since they are the one asking the question of volunteers and so the onus of making the question succinct, easier to answer, and easier to understand should be on them. Thus was born the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

Regarding,

> Most people seem to have forgotten, their beginnings at computer science.
> Not everyone is a genius and have to start somewhere.
> they a tutorial and start but as they still struggle with the basis and they haven't learned how to debug their code.

Question curation has been and should remain focused on the question itself and not on the poster or their level of experience or training. Again, this is not a tutorial site nor even a help site but a question and answer site.

Comment: But the real beauty of the MRE is as you reduce the code to focus on the bug, you isolate the bug  and denoise it. Usually you don't even finish the MRE before you can see the bug through the remaining noise and squash it. If you finish the MRE and have an example program that is the bug, the whole bug, and nothing but the bug and still can't solve it you either have a really tough problem that's going to need the attentions of an expert in the field or you are missing a key piece of information  and someone will be able to tell you what that is very, very quickly.

Comment: @user4581301: I'm 100% with you. The MRE process can help you expose the bug in all its nakedness, and the process itself is an amazing learning experience. That being said, no one said that creating a decent MRE is easy work and as others have noted, cannot always be produced by programming students when the first start out