# Are there trends towards being "more welcoming"?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, welcoming

Obviously it is a bit early to ask, but still I am wondering if "things" are already changing.

I just used an enforced one-day cool down period to have a look around, and it *seems* to me that at least on the Java tag, there are less of the harsh comments that "not welcoming" is about (at least in my eyes that is one of the major problems).

But single "anecdotal" stories aren't evidence. Therefore I am wondering: are there any statistics (or better: observable trends) that indicate of changing behavior, as in:

- *Has the number of flagged comments increased? Already answered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367768/7296893)*
- Have our moderators decided to be more sensitive, as in: not only delete comments where required, but also get back to users more often?
- Do you flag more often now, or do you comment on "unwelcoming" comments more often now?

(For the record: this is not a complaint about getting suspended. I was too sarcastic and agree that changing "tone" will indeed be a helpful practice for me.)

Comment: Welcome to Meta! Please not that voting here doesn't always reflect the quality of your question; [it might indicate (dis)agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: </obvious sarcasm>

Comment: @Glorfindel I came here to let go of all sarcasm. And now that. Sigh.

Comment: It could also be that people simple write their comments in a less *unwelcoming* way.

Comment: There seems to be a trend where people post a lot of questions about [tag:welcoming]. Or using it as a shield/weapon.

Comment: Two notable statistics I saw.  The number of downvotes fell by ~20%, but is slowly recovering.  The number of bountied questions jumped up from the usual low 300s to 400+.  Whether that's because lousy questions don't get closed anymore and can progress to a bounty or that skilled contributors exited the building is not obvious to me yet.

Comment: @AndréKool That link doesn't list any questions. Are you sure you meant a SO tag "welcoming", not the MSO one?

Comment: @GhostCat You are completely right. I made a mistake and typed to fast. I was planning on linking to [welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming)

Comment: @HansPassant Could it be that since everyone is more welcoming, people put in more effort because they feel appreciated, and thus quality has increased substantially, so less downvotes are needed, and more people are starting bounties to award draw attention to the new influx of high-quality questions and answers?

Comment: Oh wait no that's totally ridiculous, ignore my previous comment

Comment: Ask again after 'Homework Sunday':(

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this question, however, I'd like to see how (if at all) it correlates with question quality. Has being "nicer" resulted in better or worse content? Though I suspect we don't really have enough data to work with.

Comment: [quoting self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367319/839601), "just wait for a few months and you will probably see something like that happening again. As long as poor content floods the site and as long as quality measures are insufficient to manage it, there will always be multiple snarky comments from frustrated site regulars..."

Comment: I noted a small change in comments asking low rep users to clarify or improve their questions, mostly by explaining shortly the goal of some rules, or "human" tones with parts that were considered as noise such as "Good Luck". Wouldn't say improve in number of comments, but in quality (seems there are about same "dry" comments than before, or not really noticeable to me)

Comment: @BDL In that case it would indeed still be a trend toward being more welcoming.

Comment: @gnat so is the solution to a more welcoming stack overflow just to get rid of the snarky regulars? \*insert thinking emoticon here\*

Comment: I think more people just more likely to stick to *down vote/vote to close, move on* and are even more likely to ignore or flag *down voter explain* as rude/no longer needed and the mods are more likely to delete those as well, if anything.

Comment: *more welcoming* is the same as *less unwelcoming* and I have not seen any proof that there is/was any systemic intentional *unwelcoming* behavior that any significant portion of the community was engaged in to begin with so I am not really sure this question is based on anything the community can affect to begin with. *feeling* welcomed/unwelcomed is 100% on the *feeler*. They are the only person in control of how they feel. If some random person clicking on an arrow makes them feel something, it is not the random clicking persons fault or responsibility, only the *feeler* can change it.

Comment: I find it weird that this question -- a conversation starter which is straightforward and not acutely opinionated -- currently has twelve downvotes amidst a +13/-12 vote split.

Comment: @duplode, I'm an upvoter. But perhaps people *disagree* with *having a discussion* because they're getting a bit bored of it all?

Comment: @jpp That is a plausible explanation, as unfortunate as it may be. (Why downvote a discussion just because you don't want to take part in it?)

Comment: @duplode I think the people that downvoted this could have done it from the 'been there, discussed that, can we just move on already?' perspective... I don't agree, but maybe they think all that had to be said has been said so this shouldn't be a new question

Comment: @Patrice Perhaps... I don't agree either, but further arguing this point here would get us even further into the weeds of meta meta discussion, so I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: @AndréKool Do you have examples regarding that weapon/shield point? Or has that specific topic been beaten to death in yet another `welcoming` question?

Comment: (I'm not André Kool, but) many of the recent Meta threads posted by new users who feel wronged allude to the blog post. I don't think such threads have actually become more frequent, or more incisive -- it is just that their authors have added "welcoming" to their rhetorical arsenal, and I hazard the Meta threads would come into being even without the blog post. @GhostCat

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seen a lot more upvotes on trash posts from low-rep users.

Comment: I might not be typical, but I have quit answering questions or commenting on them until this blows over.

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way but I wonder how you guys can be suspended for commenting (honest question, not nagging). I tend to issue curt but somehow constructive comments (like "it cannot work, your code is flawed") and never had any issues. Or is it the java tag?

Comment: Well, there were no statistics to back up the original "unwelcoming" post, so why should there be statistics for being "more welcoming"? We just need to wait until people express their feelings; that's the only possible thing we can do, since we packed up "our magnifying glass and clue kit"...

Comment: Just as we didn't have a good way of measuring how to make good documentation (other than asking for people's often-disparate opinions on it), we don't have a way of measuring welcoming-ness either. For those of you who remember [Warlords of Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) this might all start to sound rather familiar....

Answer (score 11):

Voting data is fun, but inconclusive.

There *might*, be a slight drop in [the **percent of downvotes**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855779/history-of-downvote-and-downvotes-per-user-over-time#graph):

[image: Tiny blip down in downvote percent]

But, [the **downvote percent just against "low-rep users"**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855792/history-of-down-vote-percent-on-low-rep-users-over-time?RepCutoff=15#graph) doesn't look promising:

[image: Downvote % on posts by low-rep users]

But that trailing spike may be because of posts bound for deletion that aren't present in older data?

Comment: You can use the PostsWithDeleted table. It will be only useful for the later table https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855843/history-of-down-vote-percent-on-low-rep-users-over-time?RepCutoff=15#graph, through not seeing much difference.

Comment: @Braiam, [`OwnerUserId` is nulled out on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/148310), so that doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, well, that only leaves Shog.

Comment: Shog and/or waiting a few more weeks and rechecking...

Comment: I don't think down votes are indicators of "un-welcoming-ness" of the site. If anything, that drop in the down votes is concerning because a considerable amount of poor questions might be getting through.

Comment: @NisargShah, The writers of the original blog post disagree and downvotes are an evergreen complaint.  But even if you were right, the original claims need to be examined with objective data.

Comment: @NisargShah, Not only do **users frequently complain about downvotes, but the whole system is deliberately set up to favor upvotes and discourage dwnvotes.**  Downvotes: (1) Barely effect the recipient's rep (2) Downvotes on answers *cost*. Do the right thing by downvoting a bad answer and it penalizes *you* as well as the bad content purveyor!  (3) Downvotes swing 3 to 5 *times* less rep than upvotes (4) The requirements to downvote are 8 times higher than to upvote. (4) Downvoting posts often triggers meta complaints -- costing mod effort. **All because downvotes ARE viewed as unwelcoming.**

Comment: @Brock I would phrase that last sentence slightly differently: ["All because downvotes are VIEWED as unwelcoming."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366889/5894241) Also, among the examples given in the answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366867/5894241), I don't see anything pointing at downvotes being the *core* problem.

Comment: @NisargShah, who said it was the *core* problem? It's one more clue about whether an issue really exists and how severe it might be.  Downvotes are one way of being "Unwelcoming" and you just linked to one of the great many posts making that clear. But you claimed the opposite in your original comment!

Comment: @Brock *Downvotes are one way of being "Unwelcoming"* - No, they are intended to control quality. I don't think downvotes are the problem, the problem is that they are perceived as unwelcoming. Those are two different things. A drop in downvotes doesn't mean that individually they are also perceived as less unwelcoming. If SO really thinks downvotes are the problem, they should remove the downvote buttons. Problem solved.

Comment: What you are seeing in those charts is, people misled by that blog (and subsequent meta posts) into believing that not casting downvotes on poor questions will magically make the site more welcoming.

Comment: Downvotes are not unwelcoming in themsevles, they are 'felt' as unwelcoming because they often appear instead of an answer.  The only thing that matters is that no answer has appeared.  If there are downvotes, it must be the downvotes that prevented an answer appearing.  If there is a comment, it must be the comment author that prevented an answer appearing.  Anythng, at all, that is not an answer is unwelcoming.  Downvotes. mods, curators, comments are all unwelcome because I DON'T HAVE MY ANSWER AND ITS SOMETHING OR SOMEBODY'S FAULT!

Comment: I think it would be natural if those spikes escalate during periods when lots of programming assignments have to be finished in school. How consistent such periods are world-wide, I don't know. Just before Christmas might be one such period at least in western countries. The majority of SO users are located in Europe, US and India.

Comment: @BrockAdams I played a bit with your SEDE query for low rep users. If I enter 1 or 3 as max reputation, downvote percentages reach above 95%, if I enter 5 it falls slightly below 95% . These numbers are however relative, so I wonder what happens when we plot this against the actual amount of new users.

Comment: @Luuklag, keep in mind that it approaches 100% for such users that have < 5 rep *now*, but whose posts were made *years* ago. (And the monthly sample of such posts that weren't deleted gets much smaller.)  What we really need is a record of what the user rep was when the vote was placed, but that data is not in SEDE.

Comment: @BrockAdams just for my understanding. You currently have the ratio between up and down votes on posts of a user with less then X reputation in a given month. Wouldn't it be more helpfull to see what percent of downvotes on posts created in month X are on posts from users with less then X rep?

Comment: @Luuklag, probably not, but feel free to make that query.  That figure would also require you to normalize by the ratio of posts by low-rep users over all posts (per month).

Comment: @BrockAdams, wish I knew SQL that well ;)

Comment: Whelp, with the start of a new month, we see that plot one's downtick [isn't carrying into June](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855779/history-of-downvote-and-downvotes-per-user-over-time#graph)...