# What is the site-wide ratio of deleted comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-flags, statistics, deleted-comments

What is the site-wide ratio of deleted comments? In addition, it would be also nice to know:

- A breakdown of the deleted comments by deletion trigger, including the various flag types as well as self-deletion; and
- The ratio of deleted comments within the previous day, week, month and year, which would give a rough idea of how deletion takes place over time.

My motivation for asking this is gathering information that might be relevant for discussions about comment management.

Comment: Do any of Jon's older stats [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling/251176#251176) help?

Comment: Shog was talking about this in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6938827#6938827) at the beginning of May... the stats aren't *exactly* what you're looking for, but it might give you a start. ~10%  total deleted over the last year, of which 26% were deleted by mods and 68% by the authors... presumably the rest (6%) by flags without mod intervention.

Comment: @BradLarson That is useful; thanks. I hazard the older data is still relevant (I don't see many reasons to suspect a major change in flagging behaviour), though it would be nice to see how it looks like after the latest flag reform.

Comment: @Catija Thank you; that answers the main question for my purposes. (Any extra stats on the top of that would be a bonus.)

Comment: Hmm, no, there was rather a major change.  What is the use of this data, what would you compare it to to eke meaning out of the raw numbers?

Comment: @HansPassant Personally, I'm not so much looking for trends (as in questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368511/2751851)) as for estimates of the raw volume, for the benefit of evaluating suggestions such as those about rate limits for comments.

Comment: @Catija A category you missed for the remaining 6% may be comments attached to deleted posts.

Comment: @jpmc26 Comments still existent on deleted posts don't count as "deleted" comments. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, here are some quick stats:

Over the past 365 days, 12,681,170 comments were created.

Of these, just about 10% were deleted... For the following reasons:

```
Reasons                                                                               DeletedComments 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- 
 Self-deleted                                                                         877718          
 Automated deletion                                                                   154071          
 CommentNoLongerNeeded                                                                120808          
 Moderator discretion                                                                 83276           
 Comment Rude Or Offensive                                                            11096           
 Comment Obsolete                                                                     6970            
 Comment Too Chatty                                                                   3079            
 Comment Other                                                                        2657            
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic                                                2573            
 Comment Rude Or Offensive, CommentNoLongerNeeded                                     619             
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Rude Or Offensive                     117             
 Comment Other, CommentNoLongerNeeded                                                 106             
 Comment Other, Comment Rude Or Offensive                                             77              
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Too Chatty                            30              
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Other                                 18              
 Comment Other, Comment Rude Or Offensive, CommentNoLongerNeeded                      9               
 Comment Rude Or Offensive, Comment Too Chatty                                        8               
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Obsolete                              8               
 Comment Obsolete, Comment Other                                                      7               
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Rude Or Offensive, Comment Too Chatty 6               
 Comment Obsolete, Comment Too Chatty                                                 5               
 Comment Obsolete, Comment Rude Or Offensive                                          4               
 Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic, Comment Obsolete, Comment Rude Or Offensive   2               
 Comment Other, Comment Too Chatty                                                    1
```

As you can see, self-deletion accounts for the majority of deleted comments. "Automated deletion" deserves a bit of explanation - these are comments that are deleted automatically by the system *without being flagged* - so, stuff like the "possible duplicate" comments or the deletion explanation comments left from review; these are comments that are created *for* a user *by* the system, and also cleaned up by the system when no longer needed.

Here's a little chart of the percentage of comments created which are later deleted, by week, for the past 365 days.

[image: percent of comments created that are later deleted, by week]

#### See also: [Was there an uptick in comment flags after the "be nicer" blog post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367768/was-there-an-uptick-in-comment-flags-after-the-be-nicer-blog-post/367769#367769)

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure: do the "Comment [...]" categories correspond to comments automatically deleted by flag accumulation (as opposed to "Moderator discretion", which covers manual deletion by mods)?

Comment: @duplode moderator discretion probably means: the moderator saw it, and deleted it, without being reported.

Comment: If a moderator OR the system deleted a comment in response to a flag, it'll be categorized for that reason, @duplode. "Moderator discretion" covers comments deleted with no pending flag (on that comment; there will often have been flags on other comments or posts in the thread).

Comment: @Braiam and Shog: That makes sense, and means the data here gives us the shares of each kind of flag among the "successful" flags.

Comment: 12 million comments in a year? Am I reading that right? what the ...

Comment: @Magisch That is not so scary once we consider there are [about 6 million posts in a year](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/857736/number-of-posts-created-over-the-last-365-days), including deleted ones.